# In the verbatim environment, how can I display an 'if' statement I declared as '\ifcondition'?

Tags: macros, errors, verbatim, conditionals

I have declared a couple of `if` commands of the form

```
\newif\iffinal
\newif\ifsolutions
```

Now I want to write about it in the same document! So I want to write something like

```
\iffinal

    (...)

    \begin{verbatim}

        \iffinal
        \ifsolutions

    \end{verbatim}

    (...)

\fi
```

that displays the syntax of the commands, but I keep getting the following error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line [NUMBER]
```

whenever I include my verbatim environment within the scope of a condition that is commented out like

```
%\iffinal
```

If the condition is not commented out:

```
\iffinal
```

the verbatim environment works fine.

`line [NUMBER]` is the last place where I used one of my declared `if` conditions.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal and complete version of the problematic code?

Comment: When TeX skips over the commented text, it will not see the verbatim environment, and it will try to properly nest the `\if` and `\fi`. I only have a solution when there is an even number of extra `\if`. You can try to add `\let\fi\fi` after the verbatim environment: if it is skipped over, TeX will see those as closing the previous two `\if` s; otherwise `\let\fi\fi` just redefines `\fi` to be `\fi` (i.e. it does nothing).

Comment: @Bruno: How about `\def\foo{\fi\fi}`. That would let you add an arbitrary amount of `\fi`s (just make sure that `\foo` isn't used anywhere else).

Comment: @Caramdir: you could post this as a solution. Using `\begingroup...\endgroup` will make the definition local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When TeX encounters an `\if` and the test is false, it starts looking for the matching `\fi` without expanding anything inbetween and ignoring any braces (as expanding might have side-effects). From TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic`):

> `\if... ... \fi` and the result of the
>   test is false. After the test TeX will
>   start skipping material without
>   expansion, without counting braces,
>   but balancing nested conditionals,
>   until a `\fi` token is encountered. If
>   the `\fi` is not found an error message
>   results at the end of the file:
>
> > `Incomplete \if...; all text was ignored after line ...`
>
> where the line
>   number indicated is that of the line
>   where TEX started skipping, that is,
>   where the conditional occurred.

So in your case, TeX encounters the `\iffinal` and starts looking for the matching `\fi`. Since `\begin{verbatim}` is not expanded, its catcode trickery never gets applied, so that TeX sees the two `\if`s inside the verbatim environment. It matches the `\ifsolutions` with the `\fi` and the two other `\if`s don't match with anything, prompting the error.

The solution is to add two `\fi`s after the verbatim in such a way that they don't do anything. One possibility is `{\def\foo{\fi\fi}}` (the braces are there so that the assignment is gets reverted immediately):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iffinal
\newif\ifsolutions
\finaltrue
\begin{document}
\iffinal
    (...)
    \begin{verbatim}
        \iffinal
        \ifsolutions
    \end{verbatim}
    {\def\foo{\fi\fi}}
    (...)
\fi
\end{document}
```

There are of course other ways to achieve the same goal. For example inventing a new comment character:

```
{\catcode`@=14
@\fi\fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to avoid these issues is to not use if-switches for such code. The `comment` package allows you to define environments which are simply transparent or ignore their content like comments (i.e. the content is skipped verbatim). These environments then don't clash with the if-switches in the verbatim code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
%\includecomment{final}% instead of \finaltrue (or triggered by \iffinal) 
\excludecomment{final}% instead of \finalfalse (or triggered by \iffinal\else)

\begin{document}
% ...
\begin{final}

    (...)

    \begin{verbatim}

        \iffinal
        \ifsolutions

    \end{verbatim}

    (...)

\end{final}
% ...
\end{document}
```