# Environments with conditionals in: why doesn't this work?

Tags: environments, conditionals

In response to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14611/215) I thought the obvious thing to do was the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iffoo
\newenvironment{foobar}{\iffoo}{\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{foobar}
  Here is text
\end{foobar}
Here is more text
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work: `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 5.`

If, however, I add a `\footrue` to the preamble it compiles fine. Adding `\foofalse` does not make it work.

Could someone explain this behaviour? This sort of thing is possible: the `comment` package does exactly this. I am not asking how to achieve this behaviour. My question is: why doesn't this thing work in LaTeX "out of the box"?

Comment: Compare also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14538/in-the-verbatim-environment-how-can-i-display-an-if-statement-i-declared-as

Comment: Remark, see [conditionals - Hide custom environment content based on boolean - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/hide-custom-environment-content-based-on-boolean) for *other* ways to make this work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TeX is skipping all input tokens (macros, characters, ...) after a conditional which is logical *false* but looks at every one to see if it is a `\fi` token (i.e. `\fi` or any macro `\let` to it; see also [What is an if?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12015/what-is-an-if)). It doesn't expand macros. So the `\fi` in `\end{foobar}` is never seen, just `\end` followed by the tokens `{`, `f`, ..., `r`, `}`. However after a logical true `if` the tokens are processed as normal and TeX simply remembers to take the next `\fi` it encounters on the way as the end of the currently processed *if*-branch.

So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iffoo
\let\foobar=\iffalse
\let\endfoobar=\fi
\begin{document}
\foobar
  Here is text
\endfoobar
Here is more text
\end{document}
```

would work, but there is no way to make that work with LaTeX style environments. The `comment` package skips everything verbatim to the `\end{comment}` marker (which is also read verbatim!).

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 17):

Martin gave a very nice answer explaining why it doesn't work. Here's a way to get what you want (assuming your minimal example shows what you want and not just the problem) using Will's `environ` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\iffoo
\NewEnviron{foobar}{\iffoo\expandafter\BODY\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{foobar}
Here is some foobar text 1.
\end{foobar}
\footrue
\begin{foobar}
Here is some foobar text 2.
\end{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Note that I replaced `\newenvironment` with `\NewEnviron` and that the body of the environment is stored in the `\BODY` macro. This way, the environment checks `\iffoo` before expanding `\BODY`. If `\iffoo` is false, then it skips tokens until it sees `\fi` which it can do without expanding anything else.

(The `\expandafter` is only important if the last thing in the `foobar` environment is going to be looking at following tokens.)

Comment: That package looks useful!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if BODY contains a verbatim environment...