# Hide custom environment content based on boolean

Tags: environments, conditionals

I have a custom environment which adds some text around its content, but I also want it to be able to show or hide its contents depending on a boolean.

I have tried doing the following:

```
\newif\ifshow
\showfalse
\newenvironment{myenv}
{\ifshow\textbf{Content of myenv:}}
{\fi}
```

But the first `\begin{myenv}` raises an `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line X`. It would seem that the `\iffalse` is causing the `\end{myenv}` to be ignored, so the `\fi` is never written.

Any idea on how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I usually do it the other way around, i.e. define "different environments" based on the if. I use the [`comment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package for excluding the contents of the environment.

```
\usepackage{comment}
\ifshow
  \newenvironment{myenv}{\textbf{Content of myenv:}}{}
\else
  \excludecomment{myenv}
\fi
```

Comment: FYI This doesn't work with Beamer documents. I did not understand the source of the error but [this conversation](http://latex-beamer-class.10966.n7.nabble.com/problem-with-comments-style-still-persists-td728.html) indicates that the [version](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/version) package can be used in place of `comment`. So: `\usepackage{version}` and `\excludeversion{myenv}`.

Comment: `\excludecomment{}`, what a lifesaver. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Dominique You saved my day! The `\excludeversion` is the only solution that works for my section with `minted` content. Thank you, mate!

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with 2 differently named short environments (following the \maybe example in the comment package description)? I have \maybe and \alternative, and I would like to always only have either or.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do this is to use the [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) package and conditionally keep or toss the `\BODY`.

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myenv}{
  \ifshow
    \textbf{Content of myenv: \BODY}
  \fi}
```

Comment: I think `\NewEnviron{myenv}{}{` should be `\NewEnviron{myenv}{%`.

Comment: I wonder what's the difference in efficiency is between `\NewEnviron` environments and the `comment` package. The first one might be significant slower if there are a lot of sub-environments. AFAIK it scans for `\end` until the `\end{myenv}` is reached. The `comment` package skips everything verbatim instead, which has the initial catcode-change overhead.

Comment: @Martin: you're right about the syntax.  For some reason I thought you could have opening code.  As for the efficiency, I hadn't thought about it—I bet it wouldn't make a big difference until you get up to 100 pages or so.  I use the first method but it was before I found out about `environ` so I thought I would throw it out there.

Comment: The first argument is the opening code. You can set some end-code with the trailing optional argument `\NewEnviron{myenv}{code \BODY code}[<end-of-env code>]`.

Comment: This has another disadvantage, namely you can't use verbatim content inside the environment. (as well as losing synctex support)

Comment: @user202729: Quite true.

Comment: That's too bad about the verbatim, and listings don't work for me either. Otherwise this would be great, since it can be turned on and off.

Comment: @Guido listings uses the same kind of catcode hackery as verbatim, so no surprise that they both don't work

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
\newcommand\suppress[1]{}
```

in combination with

```
\newcommand\myOptElse[3]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}%
{#2\suppress{#3}}%
{\suppress{#2}#3}}% if #1 then #2 else #3
```

and a boolean variable.
This enables me to change between `#2` and `#3` with an ON/OFF switch `#1`.

Example:

```
%Declare the boolean variable    
\newboolean{showmyenv} %Testblöcke anzeigen
%
%Set to OFF
\setboolean{showmyenv}{false}
\myOptElse{showmyenv}{MyEnv content}{Alternative content} 
%the above will show "Alternative content", if you do not want any, leave it empty
%
%Set to ON
\setboolean{showmyenv}{true}
\myOptElse{showmyenv}{MyEnv content}{Alternative content} 
%the above will show "MyEnv content"
```

Comment: 1. You need to include the `ifthenelse` package for your code.  However, generally the commands from `etoolbox` should be preferred.  2. The questioner asks how to apply this to environments.  Can you give a complete working document?

Answer (score 1):

---

This is an implementation of the *non-catcode-changing* method (bullet point 2 in David's answer below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewEnviron{disposecontentinside}{}

\newif\ifshow

\newenvironment{testenv}{
    \ifshow
        \let\execute_this_when_environment_end\relax  % = do nothing when environment end
        % then do nothing
    \else
        % in this case, we want to execute \disposecontentinside here, and \enddisposecontentinside when the environment ends:
        \let\execute_this_when_environment_end\enddisposecontentinside
        \expandafter\disposecontentinside   % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do/ for explanation for the expandafters
    \fi
}{
    \execute_this_when_environment_end
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\showtrue
\begin{testenv}
    show this
\end{testenv}

\showfalse
\begin{testenv}
    hide this
\end{testenv}
\end{document}
```

Advantages...

- keep synctex (unlike [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15521/250119))
- can use \verb inside (except when it's something like `\verb+}+` then you get problems with brace balancing if `\showfalse`)
- can use inside the argument of another commands etc.
- don't need to copy paste the code of `environ` package to grab the body
- unlike [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15510/250119), it can be used even when the conditional is only known when the environment begins

---

**Other solutions** include

- Use a (plain TeX) box. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73632/250119
- Use a lrbox environment which is a (thin) wrapper over the above.

The 2 methods above has the property that the inner content are still executed instead of being "skipped over".

- The solutions mentioned in the bullet points in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73634/250119.

Comment: Example answer using bullet point 1 in David's answer (catcode-changing method for `comment` environment) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37945/250119

Answer (score 1):

When doing that for exercises/exams/etc, I want also to have a separate numbering for equations and floats (figures and tables). So my solution is to have this:

```latex
% requires ifthenelse package
\newboolean{Solucion} % True/False to show the solution
\setboolean{Solucion}{true} %

% define the color we use to typeset the solution, requires xcolor
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!40!black}
\colorlet{darkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{solcolor}{darkblue}

\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{soleq}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{solution}{\ifSolucion\color{solcolor}%
    \let\c@equation\c@soleq\def\theequation{S\thesoleq}%
\expandafter\BODY\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={\textcolor{solcolor}{Figura}}]{solfigure}
\renewcommand{\thesolfigure}{\textcolor{solcolor}{S\arabic{solfigure}}}
% This is for use with babel[Spanish,English], adapt to your case
\addto\captionsenglish{\floatname{solcolor}{Figure}}
\addto\captionsspanish{\floatname{solcolor}{Figura}}
```

This outputs the solution in a different color, and the equations are numbered independently from the main part --- so that the equation and float numbers do not change between the document with and without the solution.

[image]

You probably need to tweak that a bit (I use Spanish and English with `babel`, for example), and it could be made better (notice the color of the figure caption),  but I think it's a good starting point.