# How can I check in LaTeX (or plain TeX) whether a command exists, by name?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm looking for a LaTeX way to control macro expansion, contingent on some macro being defined or not. I'm looking for something like this (but then actually working):

```
\newcommand[1]{\checkfor}{
  \if\isdef\csname{#1}
  ... expand this if command exists ...
  \else
  ... expand this if command does not exist ...
  \fi
}
```

which can then be called using

```
\checkfor{CommandName}
```

(this example is, of course, useless. The actual code I want to use this kind of expansion in is a package that dynamically creates a large number of macros from an even larger set of possible macros, with default behaviour for "all macros". Since not "all" macros may exist, I need some way to test whether a macro was declared, before I can expand based on its value).

Comment: I'm interested in answering a variant of this: Define a command differently, depending on the existence of `\nameref` (like `\newcommand{\refn[1]{\nameref{#1}}` vs. `\newcommand{\refn}[1]{[#1]}`). I tried any of the answers, but wasn't successful.

Comment: Remember not to ask new questions in a comment section. If you have a genuinely new question, post it, and then link to this one after explaining what you're _not_ asking about (since this question has an accepted answer, so not pointing out your question isn't quite the same question as this one would probably just get your post marked as a duplicate)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\checkfor}[1]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
    ... command '#1' exists ...%
  \else%
    ... command '#1' does not exist ...%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\checkfor{CommandName}\par
\checkfor{section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps mention 'tail safe' approaches using `\@firstoftwo`/`\@secondoftwo`.

Comment: Could you expand on what 'tail safe' means or give a link? I'd like to learn more.

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry, but I don't know what 'tail safe' refers to. As a reference this question has a good discussion on: [what do firstoftwo and secondoftwo do](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do)

Comment: @PeterGrill Well, if the 'material to insert' needs to potentially use nested conditional, the leaving the `\fi` unclosed is not ideal (you get a token build up). There is also the case where the 'material' may need other arguments, which it won't 'see' with the `\fi` still there. In both of those cases, making the two branches into additional arguments of the macro and using `\expandafter\@fitstoftwo`/`\expandafter\@secondoftwo` in the branches is preferable. (Of course, for simple cases this is not required, but I'm assuming a general solution is needed.)

Comment: For those who want to try this out; take care that `{CommandName}` is without the preceding \ backslash.

Comment: People may also want to look at the documentation here:
http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef

Answer (score 40):

The `etoolbox` provides two macros for this:

```
\ifdef{<control sequence>}{<true>}{<false>}
Expands to <true> if the <control sequence> is defined, and to <false> otherwise.
Note that control sequences will be considered as defined even if their meaning
is \relax. This command is a LaTeX wrapper for the e-TeX primitive \ifdefined.

\ifcsdef{<csname>}{<true>}{<false>}
Similar to \ifdef except that it takes a control sequence name as its first argument.
This command is a LaTeX wrapper for the e-TeX primitive \ifcsname.
```

Answer (score 29):

The LaTeX kernel standard macro here is `\@ifundefined`, used as

```
\@ifundefined{foo}
  {%
    % \foo not defined
  }
  {%
    % \foo defined
  }%
```

---

In earlier LaTeX2e releases, this test was not 'expandable' and would cause `\foo` to be equal to `\relax` if it had not previously been defined. However, the kernel now uses essentially the same code as in [Peter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30484), which means that these issues are no longer present. (The change is possible as the LaTeX2e kernel now requires and uses e-TeX.)

Comment: This solution can be used to determine if the name `foo` is an existed macro. I wonder if there is a similar way to determine if the macro `\foo` exists?

Answer (score 8):

The package [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) provides `\isundefined` which apparently has slightly different semantics:

> This test differs from `\@ifundefined` in that it takes a real command—and not a command name—as
>   argument, and also in that command which is let equal to `\relax` is not considered undefined.

So what you are looking for can be implemented as:

```
\newcommand[1]{\checkfor}{
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{#1}}{%
    % expand undefined
  }{%
    % expand defined
  }%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-expandable variant of the test which does without whatsoever extensions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\checkfor[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  }{\endgroup\@firstoftwo}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\LaTeX| is \checkfor{LaTeX}{defined}{undefined}.

\verb|\relax| is \checkfor{relax}{defined}{undefined}.

\verb|\UndefiNED| is \checkfor{UndefiNED}{defined}{undefined}.

\verb|\UndefiNED| is \checkfor{UndefiNED}{defined}{undefined}.

\verb|\UndefiNED| is \checkfor{UndefiNED}{defined}{undefined}.

\end{document}
```

[image]