# Processing complex label-like expressions with pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

I would like to use `pgfkeys` to process expressions like

```
label={[scale=.8,pos=.9]above right:$-2\pi i$}
```

(which typically appear as labels in nodes), and extract from them three parameters according to the pattern `[#1]#2:#3`. I would also like to make `#1` and `#2` optional (again, as labels in nodes), so that things like `#2:#3`, `[#1]#3` and `#3` are valid patterns.

**Update:** I've been reading the `tikz` code that does this parsing, and have come up with code that works for many cases (it even allows for `#3` being optional). The code is attached below (it is a working example, but is far from minimal: sorry!).

So what is it that doesn't work? Well, the options (argument `#1`). If I just specify a value (e.g. `label={[blue]above:hola}`), it works. But if I try to make it into a list (`label={[blue,thick]above:hola}`) or a key-value pair (`label={[scale=.8]above:hola}`), the code breaks (I get an error like `I do not know the key /tikz/scale=.8`). What do I have to modify to get that working?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,calc,bending}

\pgfdeclarelayer{top}
\pgfsetlayers{main,top}

\tikzset{
  branch point/.style={cross out,draw=black,fill=none,minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth),inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}, 
  branch point/.default=5,
  branch cut/.style={
    decorate,decoration=snake
  }
}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\$=11\relax%
\gdef\parse@label[#1]#2:#3\empty{%
  % Extract options
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \relax%
  \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/options}{#1}%
  \fi%
  % Do we have an angle?
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    % Nope!
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      % We also don't have a label text
      \relax%
    \else
      % But we do have a label text, so let's extract it
       \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/text}{#2}%
    \fi%
  \else
    % Yup!
    \parse@@label#2:#3\empty%
  \fi%
}
\gdef\parse@@label#1:#2:\empty{%
  % Do we have an angle?
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \relax%
  \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/angle}{#1}%
  \fi%
  % Do we have a label text?
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \relax%
  \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/text}{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\catcode`\$=3\relax%
\pgfkeys{/branch cut jump/.cd,
  pos/.initial = .8,
  amplitude/.initial = 10,
  color/.initial = green!60!black,
  label/.code    = {
    \@ifnextchar[%
      {\parse@label}%
      {\parse@label[]}#1:\empty%
    },
  label/options/.initial = green!60!black,
  label/angle/.initial   = above right,
  label/text/.initial    = $-2\pi i$
}
\tikzset{
  place arrow/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
    execute at begin to={
      \coordinate (A) at ($(\tikztostart)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/pos}!-\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/amplitude}:(\tikztotarget)$);
      \coordinate (B) at ($(\tikztostart)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/pos}!\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/amplitude}:(\tikztotarget)$);
      \coordinate (AB/3) at ($(A)!1/3!(B)$);
      \coordinate (2AB/3) at ($(A)!2/3!(B)$);
      \coordinate (C) at ($(AB/3)!2/(3*sqrt(3))!-90:(B)$);
      \coordinate (D) at ($(2AB/3)!4/(3*sqrt(3))!-90:(B)$);
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{top}
        \draw[thick,\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/color},-{Stealth[]}] (A) .. controls (C) and (D) .. (B) node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/label/options},\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/label/angle}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/label/text}};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
  },
  branch cut jump/.style={
    /branch cut jump/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/.cd,place arrow
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=90pt,y=90pt]
\begin{scope}
  % Axes
  \draw[thin,gray,->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[thin,gray,->] (0,-1) -- (0,1) node[above] {$y$};
  % Branch point
  \draw[thick] (0,0) node[branch point,draw=red,thick] {};
  % Branch cut
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump] (0,0) to (0:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={hola}}] (0,0) to (30:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={:}}] (0,0) to (60:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={:adios}}] (0,0) to (90:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={left:}}] (0,0) to (120:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={below:$\times (-1)$}}] (0,0) to (150:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={[blue]hola}}] (0,0) to (180:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={[blue]:}}] (0,0) to (210:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={[blue]:adios}}] (0,0) to (240:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={[blue]left:}}] (0,0) to (270:1.2);
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={[blue]below:$\times (-1)$}}] (0,0) to (300:1.2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can just copy the label code.

Comment: @percusse: I'm looking at the code right now. It does way more than just extract the three values I want. Also, I find it very difficult to understand. I don't think I have the knowledge to isolate what I need from the rest.

Comment: You are currently overwriting TikZ's definitions of things. This seems like a Bad Idea. It would be better to use something like `xabel={[scale=.8,pos=.9]above right:$-2\pi i$}`. Apart from anything else, you can then pass it onto `label` if you actually want a label.

Comment: @cfr: I don't think I'm overwriting TikZ definitions, am I? I have `label` inside  `/branch cut jump`. Also, I do want something that acts as a label, but it is, in fact, a node: see the code inside the `execute at begin to` block.

Comment: I guess if you're sure that `\parse@label` etc. are unique.

Comment: Shouldn't `label/options` be a style if you want to pass a key-value list?

Comment: @cfr: I guess it should, but I've tried that and TeX gives the unhelpful error message `I don't know the key /branch cut jump`...

Comment: @cfr: `\parse@label` and company are unique. I checked using the first answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/how-can-i-check-in-latex-or-plain-tex-whether-a-command-exists-by-name

Comment: Can you provide a more minimal example? What exactly is wrong with the output of your code? It isn't very clear what the code isn't doing which it should or what it shouldn't do that it is. At least, not to me. Or at least annotate the code to indicate the node which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @cfr: I describe in the question what is wrong (it doesn't compile the moment I give options that are more than just a value). I'll try to come up with a more minimal example.

Comment: You only really need a single node, don't you? To demonstrate the issue? And you want the code to produce the error. Or at least to include code to produce the error commented out.

Comment: @cfr: I figured it out! As you suggested, I should have been using `/branch cut jump/label/.style` to set the default value instead of `/branch cut jump/label/.initial`. Then the macro parsing the label can just call `\pgfkeys{/branch cut jump/label/options/.append style={#1}}`, and I can do `node[/branch cut jump/label/options/]`. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You should write that as an answer.

Comment: I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,calc,bending}

\pgfdeclarelayer{top}
\pgfsetlayers{main,top}

\tikzset{
  branch point/.style={cross out,draw=black,fill=none,minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth),inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
  branch point/.default=5,
  branch cut/.style={
    decorate,decoration=snake
  }
}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\$=11\relax%
\gdef\parse@label[#1]#2:#3\empty{%
  % Extract options
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \relax%
  \else
    \tikzset{/branch cut jump/label/options=#1}%
  \fi%
  % Do we have an angle?
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    % Nope!
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      % We also don't have a label text
      \relax%
    \else
      % But we do have a label text, so let's extract it
       \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/text}{#2}%
    \fi%
  \else
    % Yup!
    \parse@@label#2:#3\empty%
  \fi%
}
\gdef\parse@@label#1:#2:\empty{%
  % Do we have an angle?
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \relax%
  \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/angle}{#1}%
  \fi%
  % Do we have a label text?
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \relax%
  \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/branch cut jump/label/text}{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\catcode`\$=3\relax%
\pgfkeys{/branch cut jump/.cd,
  pos/.initial = .8,
  amplitude/.initial = 10,
  color/.initial = green!60!black,
  label/.code    = {
    \@ifnextchar[%
      {\parse@label}%
      {\parse@label[]}#1:\empty%
    },
  label/options/.store in = \branch@label@options,
  label/options=green!60!black,
  label/angle/.initial   = above right,
  label/text/.initial    = $-2\pi i$
}
\tikzset{
  place arrow/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
    execute at begin to={
      \coordinate (A) at ($(\tikztostart)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/pos}!-\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/amplitude}:(\tikztotarget)$);
      \coordinate (B) at ($(\tikztostart)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/pos}!\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/amplitude}:(\tikztotarget)$);
      \coordinate (AB/3) at ($(A)!1/3!(B)$);
      \coordinate (2AB/3) at ($(A)!2/3!(B)$);
      \coordinate (C) at ($(AB/3)!2/(3*sqrt(3))!-90:(B)$);
      \coordinate (D) at ($(2AB/3)!4/(3*sqrt(3))!-90:(B)$);
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{top}
        \draw[thick,\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/color},-{Stealth[]}] (A) .. controls (C) and (D) .. (B) node[\branch@label@options,\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/label/angle}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/branch cut jump/label/text}};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
  },
  branch cut jump/.style={
    /branch cut jump/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/.cd,place arrow
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,red,branch cut,branch cut jump={label={[blue,thick]above:hola}}] (0,0) to (30:1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: node]

Comment: Not that the `thick` makes a difference here since it is a node which is not drawn but it doesn't produce an error....

Comment: Not exactly sure why, but these leaks styles up to the whole `tikzpicture`: change `thick` to `scale=3` and the whole `tikzpicture` expands!

Comment: Hmmm.... That's odd. I guess it is a good thing that the `style` suggestion worked ;).