# How to put hyperlinks in endfloat's markers?

Tags: floats, endfloat

The documentation of the [endfloat](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat?lang=en) package explains how to customize the text in the markers from the default of "[Table 3 about here.]"  But I would like to customize the markers to include a hyperlink to the figure at the end of the document.  How can this be accomplished?

Here's a subquestion:  In customizing the marker, `\thepostfigure` refers to the figure number.  Is there a similar command like `\thefigurereference` that refers to the reference to the figure, so that the marker text can be something like `Figure \ref{\thefigurereference}} about here.`?

**Update 2:** In the comments, I asked about a backlink as well, so that the caption of the figure at the end of the document would hyperlink back to the "[Figure 1 about here]" float embedded in the text.  @John Kormylo's accepted solution delivers this.

**Update 1 [edited to be clearer it's referring to @John Kormylo's original answer, not his revised one]:**

@John Kormylo's (original) solution works, but as I have learned it is incompatible with the subcaption package.  So, my revised question is: Is there a way to hyperlink to figures that still works with caption?

Here is a MWE using his solution where the hyperlinks don't go to the figures at the end.  Figure 2 is just there to demonstrate why I need subcaption - the linking still fails even without it, so long as the subpcaption package is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% John Kormylo's original solution, which works when the subcaption package isn't used:
\renewcommand{\floatplace}[1]{% #1 = float type (e.g. figure)
   \begin{center}
     \hyperlink{#1.\csname thepost#1\endcsname}%
       {[\csname #1name\endcsname~\csname thepost#1\endcsname\ about here.]}
   \end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{A figure without subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{first part}
\end{subfigure}%
%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{(second part)}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]


\end{document}
```

The `aux` file produced suggests that the reason the solution didn't work is that subcaption changes the name of the counters from `figure.1`, `figure.2` etc. to `figure.caption.2`, `figure.caption.3` etc.  It has these lines for the list of tables (which has working hyperlinks to the figures):

```
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces This is figure 1.\relax }}{3}{figure.caption.2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces This is figure 2.\relax }}{4}{figure.caption.3}}
```

One option would be to re-write John Kormylo's (original) `\floatplace` command starting numbering at 2 and re-naming the head to `figure.caption` or `table.caption`.  But in in a different document, the numbering for `figure.caption` in the aux file starts at 18. (I haven't figured out how to reproduce this in a MWE, though.)  This means that such a workaround won't do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: For referencing, use \label{<figure>}` in the figure and then `\ref{<figure>}` where you want the reference, where `<figure>` is whatever label you want. For hyperlinks it might be enough to include `\usepackage{hyperref}` -- if you'd included a MWE I'd test this:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\caption` calls `\refstepcounter{figure}` which creates a `\hypertarget` named `\@currentHref`.  Unfortunately, `\floatplace` only has access to `\thefigure` (actually `\thepostfigure`).  So we need to create a map from `\thefigure` to `\@currentHref` and move it up to the beginning of the document via the aux file.  To combine this and the backlink, I replaced `\caption` with `\figurecaption`.

In keeping with the original `\floatplace` I made it float type independent.  However, I only added code for `\figurecaption` and `\newfigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\floatplace}[1]{% #1 = float type (e.g. figure)
   \begin{center}
     \def\floatnumber{\csname thepost#1\endcsname}
     \def\floatname{\csname #1name\endcsname}
     \hypertarget{figureback\floatnumber}{}%
     \@ifundefined{#1anchor\floatnumber}%
       {[\floatname~\floatnumber\ about here.]}%
       {\hyperlink{\csname #1anchor\floatnumber\endcsname}%
         {[\floatname~\floatnumber\ about here.]}}
   \end{center}}

\newcommand{\figurecaption}[2][\empty]% #1=short caption (optional), #2=caption
 {\ifx\empty#1\relax \caption[#2]{\hyperlink{figureback\thefigure}{#2}}%
  \else \caption[#1]{\hyperlink{figureback\thefigure}{#2}}%
  \fi
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newfigure{\thefigure}{\@currentHref}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newfigure}[2]% #1 = \thefigure, #2 = \@currentHref
  {\expandafter\gdef\csname figureanchor#1\endcsname{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\figurecaption{A figure without subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{first part}
\end{subfigure}%
%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{(second part)}
\end{subfigure}%
\figurecaption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

This should work no matter what weird naming convention subcaption imposes.

Comment: John, your solution works in your MWE, but when I tried to use it in my document it failed.  The hyperlinks instead directed to the top of the document.  Turns out the conflict was the **subcaption** package.  Any ideas how to make the links work properly with subcaption?

Comment: I can see from the aux file that the list of figures uses references like `figure.caption.19` (for figure 1) which then proceed sequentially.  I think the increment for these labels (18 in this case) depends on the number of subfigures there are - if there are no subfigures, the increment is 1.  So if we could figure out the increment, I think we could modify your solution to work with subcaption.

Comment: Subcaption should have no effect on the figure counter (it uses a different counter).  Please provide an MWE which demonstrates the actual problem.

Comment: John, I've put up (after some delay) a MWE of the interaction between subcaption and your solution, plus my poking around in the aux file for what goes wrong.  Care to take another crack at it?

Comment: Okay, I fixed to work with subcaption.

Comment: John, that is a thing of beauty.  One extra question: How could one put a  put a link back to the float in the text in the figure's caption (say, in the words "Figure #", or a little back arrow)?

Comment: I added backlinks.

Comment: This is great - thank you John.  To make the code work even if endfloat is switched off, I added the following to the preamble so that `\renewcommand` doesn't get upset if `\floatplace` _wasn't_ defined:

 `\ifcsname floatplace\endcsname
  \else
    \newcommand{\floatplace}[1]{#1}
  \fi`.
Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/how-can-i-check-in-latex-or-plain-tex-whether-a-command-exists-by-name .  One could instead check if the `endfloat` package was loaded:
 `\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{}{
   \newcommand{\floatplace}[1]{#1}}`.

Comment: Also, I decided that if `endfloat` isn't loaded, I don't want any hyperlinks in the captions (since they all link back to the start of the document anyway).  So, surrounding the `\newcommand{\figurecaption}[2]{…}` stuff, I put `\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}  {` before and `} { \newcommand{\figurecaption}{\caption} }` after, so that `\figurecaption` doesn't have links if `endfloat` isn't loaded

Comment: John, in testing this solution, I noticed that it breaks regular in-text references (i.e. with `\ref{…}`) to the figure: They display "??", although they do link to the right place.  This is if `\label{…}` is typed after `\figurecaption{…}`, a usual.  Any fix?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I put a \bgroup...\egroup into \figurecaption just so I wouldn't have to worry about \shortcaption being used elsewhere.  In doing so I made caption's local definitions get erased.

Comment: Yep, taking out the `\bgroup … \egroup` fixed that issue.  So without them, is the worry that `\shortcaption` could be invoked inappropriately somewhere?  In the main text I tried to use it and I got an "Undefined control sequence" error, which I think bodes well.

Comment: I made a few tweaks, so make sure you have the latest edit.  There should be no \shortcaption at all now.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to do the same for tables and figures and at the same time keep an error with the glossaries package in check.
(I think it might have an own "tablecaption" function defined somewhere.)
Here you go:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor} %Farben
\usepackage{hyperref} %Links
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat} % figures mit platzhalter und dann im Anhang
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\floatplace}[1]{% #1 = float type (e.g. figure)
    \begin{center}
        \def\floatnumber{\csname thepost#1\endcsname}
        \def\floatname{\csname #1name\endcsname}

        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{figure}}% define backlink based on figure or table
        {\def\backlink{figureback\floatnumber}}%
        {\def\backlink{tableback\floatnumber}}%

        \colorbox{yellow}{\floatname}
        \colorbox{red}{\backlink}

        \colorbox{orange}{\floatnumber}
        \colorbox{green}{\csname #1anchor\floatnumber\endcsname}

        \hypertarget{\backlink}{}
        \@ifundefined{#1anchor\floatnumber}%
        {[ \floatname~\floatnumber\ about here. ]}%
        {[ \hyperlink{\csname #1anchor\floatnumber\endcsname}%
            {\floatname~\floatnumber} about here. ]}
    \end{center}
}

%for figure
\newcommand{\figurecaption}[2][\empty]% #1=short caption (optional), #2=caption
{%
    \ifx\empty#1\relax %
        \caption[#2]{\hyperlink{figureback\thefigure}{#2}}%
    \else %
        \caption[#1]{\hyperlink{figureback\thefigure}{#2}}%
    \fi
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newfigure{\thefigure}{\@currentHref}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newfigure}[2]% #1 = \thefigure, #2 = \@currentHref
{\expandafter\gdef\csname figureanchor#1\endcsname{#2}}

\makeatletter
%for table
\newcommand{\tabcaption}[2][\empty]% #1=short caption (optional), #2=caption (tabcaption instead of tablecaption for glossaries)
{%
    \ifx\empty#1\relax %
        \caption[#2]{\hyperlink{tableback\thetable}{#2}}%
    \else %
        \caption[#1]{\hyperlink{tableback\thetable}{#2}}%
    \fi
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newtable{\thetable}{\@currentHref}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newtable}[2]% #1 = \thetable, #2 = \@currentHref
{\expandafter\gdef\csname tableanchor#1\endcsname{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \tabcaption{tab}
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \figurecaption{A figure without subfigures}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{first part}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{(second part)}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \figurecaption{A figure with subfigures}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```