# How do I get list of all predefined \if commands in LaTeX?

Tags: conditionals, programming

I was trying some programming in LaTeX and found that `\ifx` was predefined, since I get an error from this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}%
\newif\ifx
\xtrue
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Then I found there is a way to check if a command exist from this answer:

[how-can-i-check-in-latex-or-plain-tex-whether-a-command-exists-by-name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/how-can-i-check-in-latex-or-plain-tex-whether-a-command-exists-by-name)

Use it to check for `\ifx`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}%
\newcommand{\checkfor}[1]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
    ... command '#1' exists ...%
  \else%
    ... command '#1' does not exist ...%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\checkfor{ifx}\par
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above says indeed that `command \ifx exists`.

But how would one get a list of all the `\ifXXXXX`s that are out there? I need to use lots of `\if` in my code to customize my build and need to make lots of new boolean variables. If there is a list out there, I can paste it on my wall next to my computer and just look at it before I use a new command instead of getting an error or having to check using code each time.

Comment: egreg has listed the primitives but every package you load may define some more. Are you sure you need to define any at all (well you never _need_ to define any new if constructs)

Comment: you can define your propre command that add a prefix to ensure that the new condition is not defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\newif` command doesn't check whether the conditional is already existing; the assumption is that a programmer using `\newif` knows what she/he is doing.

If you want an interface like `\newcommand`, load `ifthen` and use `\newboolean`; in this case

```
\newboolean{x}
```

would tell you

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \ifx already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The same with `etoolbox` and `\newbool`.

You find the list of primitive conditionals in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic. Add to them the e-TeX conditionals

```
\ifdefined
\ifcsname
\iffontchar
```

In the manual for e-TeX (`texdoc etex`) you find the complete list

[image]

Already loaded package might have added to the list.

Some engines also add to the list; for instance `pdftex` adds

```
\ifincsname
\ifpdfprimitive
\ifpdfabsnum
\ifpdfabsdim
```

The conditional `\ifpdfprimitive` is `\ifprimitive` in XeTeX. Similarly, LuaTeX has `\ifprimitive`, `\ifabsnum` and `\ifabsdim`. Both engines share `\ifincsname`.

Comment: Don't forget about the pdfTeX conditionals (and their renamed counterparts in Xe/LuaTeX).

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, you're right

Comment: Also it might be worth mentioning the boolean type of `l3prg` (`\bool_new:N` does name checking).