# How to check if a command is empty, with a variable name?

Tags: csname

I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand\checkit{
  \ifx\csname foo\romannumeral\the\value{bar}\endcsname\empty
    empty
  \fi
}
\newcommand\foovi{hello}
\setcounter{bar}{6}
\checkit
\renewcommand\foovi{}
\checkit
\end{document}
```

I'm getting an empty document, while a single word "empty" is expected. What's wrong?

Comment: @Mico can you please suggest how to rewrite this better? I'm not married to `\ifx`, any other options are welcome!

Comment: Have you consulted the posting [How can I check in LaTeX (or plain TeX) whether a command exists, by name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30483/5001)?

Comment: Then you probably also saw Joseph Wright's warning, right? I'd give [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30486/5001) a try: `\makeatletter \newcommand\checkit{The command foo\romannumeral\the\value{bar} \@ifundefined{foo\romannumeral\the\value{bar}}{ doesn't exist!}{ exists: \csname foo\romannumeral\the\value{bar}\endcsname{}}} \makeatother`.

Comment: @Mico you are right, I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `\expandafter` missing. Beside this: there is a difference if a command is defined as long or as short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand\checkit{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname foo\romannumeral\value{bar}\endcsname\empty
    empty
  \fi
}
\newcommand\foovi{hello}
\setcounter{bar}{6}
1. \checkit

\renewcommand\foovi{}
2. \checkit

\renewcommand*\foovi{}
3. \checkit

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues with your code:

- `\ifx` doesn't expand its arguments, but only compares the first two tokens following it, in your case `\csname` and `f`, which always yields false. You need to use `\expandafter` to build the `\csname` before `\ifx` does its job.
- the macro `\empty` is short (meaning it doesn't use `\long` in its definition), whereas macros created with `\newcommand` are by default `\long`. You'll need to use `\newcommand*` and `\renewcommand*`, or after the first `\newcommand*` directly `\def` instead of `\renewcommand*`.
- your macro's replacement text starts with a spurious space, you have to comment out the line ending after `{`, like so: `\newcommand\checkit{%`. You don't have to comment out line endings after macro names, so the line containing the `\ifx` and `\fi` are fine, another (possibly) unwanted space occures after the word `empty`.

I don't know what should happen in the case that `\foovi` isn't yet defined, so I decided to let this case throw the `<false>` branch. You can easily change that if you want.

I defined your macro `\checkit` to take two arguments (not immediately, but the used `\@secondoftwo`, `\@secondofthree` and possibly `\@firstoftwo` will take those arguments). So the macro will now behave as `\checkit{<true>}{<false>}` and execute the corresponding branch if the macro has the meaning `\@empty` (which is the same as `\empty`, but since we're in `\makeatletter` we could as well use the less likely to be redefined macro `\@empty`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcounter{bar}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\newcommand\checkit
  {%
    \@ifundefined{foo\romannumeral\value{bar}}%
      {%
        % undefined
        \@secondoftwo % should result in <false>
        %\@firstoftwo % should result in <true>
      }
      {%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname foo\romannumeral\value{bar}\endcsname\@empty
          \expandafter\@secondofthree
        \fi
        \@secondoftwo
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{bar}{6}
\checkit{empty}{not empty}

\newcommand*\foovi{hello}
\checkit{empty}{not empty}

\renewcommand*\foovi{}
\checkit{empty}{not empty}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've been bitten by `\long` status. The macro `\empty` is no `\long`, equivalent to `\newcommand*\empty{}`. However, you are using `\renewcommand` for `\foovi`, so it's `\long` and not `\ifx` equal to `\empty`. If you use `\renewcommand*\foovi` then all will be well.

Comment: The other answers also mention the `\expandafter` needed for `\ifx`.