# problem with \ifthenelse + multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, conditionals

I encounter various problems when i want to control the display of a table with a `ifthenelse` test. For example, consider the following M(non)WE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\essai}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b \\ \hline
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{coucou}}{\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{oui - #1} \\ \hline}{non&#1 \\ \hline} 
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
  \essai{coucou}
\end{document}
```

If i call `\essai{hallo}`, then the `ifthenelse` test is `false`, and it compiles : the second line of the table has 2 columns, as expected.
If i call `\essai{coucou}`, then the test is `true` and i would expect to have a multicolumn line. But it gives a compilation error `Misplaced \omit...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\multicolumn` must be the first thing TeX sees in a table cell, after expanding commands; unfortunately, the workings of `\ifthenelse` leave something before `\multicolumn` when the test is computed false.

Use a different test making command: in this case, `\ifboolexpe` from `etoolbox` (notice the final "e"), might seem promising.

Unfortunately, also the way `etoolbox` implements the string equality test leads to unexpandable commands before TeX can see `\multicolumn`, so a direct approach must be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\roystreqtest}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\essai}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  a&b \\ \hline
  \roystreqtest{#1}{coucou}%
    {\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{oui - #1} \\ \hline}
    {non&#1 \\ \hline} 
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\essai{coucou}

\essai{noncoucou}
\end{document}
```

If you have to compare strings that are not made only of ASCII printable characters, it's safer to say

```
\newcommand{\roystreqtest}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
```

If you're bold, you can use an already defined infrastructure: LaTeX3 provides an expandable equality test for strings: the definition of `\roystreqtest` can be

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \roystreqtest \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and the rest would be the same.

Comment: I always wanted to learn how to use etoolbox, by i was scarred by the number of different commands, and the lack of examples in the documentation. It would help me if you could give me the synthaxe for my example (the test #1 = coucou)

Comment: thanks. Could you explain what the `\z@` does ?

Comment: After `\makeatletter`, one can use `\z@` to represent either the constant 0 or the length 0pt.

Comment: and why not simply putting `0` at this place ? because the `\ifnum` expects a command and not a number ?

Comment: It's a habit; writing 0 is good, provided a space (or end-of-line) follows it: `\ifnum...=0\@firstoftwo...\fi` might give unexpected results. Conversely, `\z@\@firstoftwo` would be safe.

Comment: ok. Happy to learn a new good habit :)

Comment: may i ask  : How does act the \expandafter in your example ?

Comment: It gets rid of `\else` or `\fi`; look in the site for it and you'll find many instances.

Comment: `\z@` is quicker than 0 as it's a token that is already a number and so doesn't scan ahead. "0 " scans ahead and consumes the space "0foo" scans ahead and re-inserts the f into the input. Probably these days it's not noticeable but in 1980's it could save you enough time to go for a coffee:-)

Comment: @egreg: About the `\expandafter` : it only influences the speed of compilation, but removing them does not change the functionality of the command, am i right  ?

Comment: @nicolasroy No, they are essential. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21263/4427)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. NEvertheless i encounter the following problem : I want to give `\roystreqtest` the caracter • as argument (it is the place holder in the TeX editor TexMaker), but the compilation says : `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
`. Why ?

Comment: @nicolasroy See edit

Comment: My next problem, is that the arguments in the command `roystreqtest` could be more complicated. They could contain some commands or some environnement. For example `\begin{itemize}\item one\item two\end{itemize}`. In this case, the compilation fails...

Comment: @nicolasroy Please, make a follow-up question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know what a "follow-up question" is...

Comment: @nicolasroy You're using the code I provided, but I can't know which one; modifying the question is not recommended, so you should write a new question, stating the problem with a MWE and put a link to this question.

Comment: ok. understood.

Answer (score 9):

If you are an old timer and not using e* tools then you need to hide the conditionals from TeX's alignment scanner. This is tricky in general but if you know your test is always the first thing in a row (ie always in the first cell in a row) then you can do the tests in a `\noalign` and come out with a suitably defined temporary macro.

This seems to work for your example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\essai}[1]{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b \\ \hline
\noalign{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{coucou}}%
        {\gdef\hmm{\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{oui - #1} \\ \hline}}%
        {\gdef\hmm{non&#1 \\ \hline}}%
}\hmm 
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

  \essai{coucou}

  \essai{xoucou}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks you for this interesting solution. What does `\noalign` do exactly ?

Comment: `\noalign` is a TeX primitive designed so that you can put in some vertical matter for example a paragraph that does not take part in the table, and then the table rows continue afterwards. The amsmath alignments have a command that uses noalign in this way but if you search for noalign in the latex sources (eg latex.ltx) you'll see it is used all over the place for the reason given here. It is used in processing ` \\ ` so it can handle looking for optional arguments, it's used in `\hline` to hide the code that looks for a following `\hline` again so that `\multicolumn` works. etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can do your tests outside the `\table`:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{expr}}
    {\gdef\temp{\multicolumn{...}}}
    {\gdef\temp{something else}}
...
\begin{tabular}{..}
...\\
\temp
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides a command `\Block` which gives features similar to `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`.

There is no problem using `\Block` inside `\ifthenelse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\essai}[1]{
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    text & text \\ \hline
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{coucou}}{\Block{1-2}{oui - #1} \\ \hline} {non&#1 \\ \hline} 
\end{NiceTabular}
}
\begin{document}
  \essai{coucou}
\end{document}
```