# How to specify a default value for overlay specification in \newcommand<>?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>{\mycommand}[1]{\textcolor#2{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
 \frame{
  \mycommand{test}
 }
\end{document}
```

I want the command to take a default overlay specification (say, `<2,4>`) that will be enabled if the command is called like in the example, without overlay spec., and overwritten if the command is called with an overlay specification (say, `\mycommand<1-4>`).

Is this possibile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (at least) possible by means of using TeX conditionals.

You need to test `#2` for emptiness. The example below uses a temporary macro to test against `\@empty` whether `#2` is empty. As `#2` only holds a few simply characters (no TeX), you could also simply do

```
\ifx\\#2\
```

to test for an empty string (if it’s empty `\ifx\\\\` will be true); instead of `\\` you can also use nearly any other control sequence that doesn’t come up in `#2` (e.g. `\relax`).

eTeX allows us to do a safe test with `\detokenize`:

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
```

There are also many packages that provide test for empty strings:

- `etoolbox`: `\ifstrempty{#2}{<true>}{<false>}`
- `xifthen`: `\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{<true>}{<false>}`

In my example, I’m using `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` so that one doesn’t need to repeat the `{red}{#2}` part of your command. It is also preferable to use them for many other reason (see the references), especially if you want to nest `\if`s.

Of course, in this simple example you don’t necessarily need this.

#### References

- [What does `\ifx\\#1\\` stand for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33823/16595)
- [What do `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/16595)
- [Why the `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` idiom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107753/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand<>{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\textcolor<2,4>}{\textcolor#2}{red}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \frame{\mycommand{test}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, works. Any particular reason why you're using `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` and `\expandafter\@secondoftwo` instead of directly loading `{\textcolor<2,4>{red}{#1}}` and `{\textcolor#2{red}{#1}}}` after `ifx` and `else`?

Comment: @Lep Out of habit. In this simple case you don’t need them really. Though, I have updated my answer with a few references and an explanation. The core is: Test for empty `#2`. How you do that and what you do with that is basically just a question of taste, purpose and if you want to load packages. There are probably a few questions on how to test for empty strings.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. As long as a beamer based answer does not show up I will accept yours.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\newcommand<>\mycommand[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax \textcolor<2,4>{red}{#1}% #2 is empty
  \else              \textcolor#2{red}{#1}%
  \fi}
\begin{document}

 \frame{\mycommand{test}}
 \frame{\mycommand<1>{test}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s optional delimiter `D`-specification:

> `o` A standard LaTeX optional argument, surrounded with square brackets, which will supply the special `-NoValue-` marker if not given (as described later).
>
> `d` Given as `d<token1><token2>`, an optional argument which is delimited by `<token1>` and `<token2>`. As with `o`, if no value is given the special marker `-NoValue-` is returned.
>
> `D` Given as `D<token1><token2>{<default>}`, it is as for `d`, but returns `<default>` if no value is given. Internally, the `o`, `d` and `O` types are short-cuts to an appropriated constructed `D` type argument.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% If you don't have an up-to-date TeX distribution, include xparse manually
% \usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ D<>{2,4} m }{%
  \textcolor<#1>{red}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \mycommand{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `beamer` allows `<>` between any arguments, so it's not 100% the same as `ltcmd`/`xparse` here

Comment: @JosephWright: Right. I'm just addressing the question as it is stated.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630126/142706) is better than mine.

---

I was able to achieve this with [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{O{<2,4>} m}{\textcolor#1{red}{#2}}
```

One problem with this solution is having to use `[ ]'s` to wrap the overlay specification around like so:

```
\mycommand[<1-4>]{test}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{O{<2,4>} m}{\textcolor#1{red}{#2}}

\begin{document}
 \frame{
  \mycommand{test}
  \mycommand[<1-4>]{test}
 }
\end{document}
```