# How do I make a list of items in Latex using recursion

Tags: itemize, recursion

I was trying to use recursion in LaTeX to create a list of items. I don't have much experience with LaTeX so kindly explain any uncommon commands used.
Here's my code for the same.

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\@itemsi{\@ifnextchar\stopitems{}{\@add}}

\newcommand\@add[1]{
  \item #1
  \@itemsi
}

\newcommand\@newitems{
    \begin{itemize}
    \@itemsi
    \end{itemize}
}

\makeatother
```

This is the output I'm getting using this code

```
\@newitems
{Fruits}
{Vegetables}
{Drink}
\stopitems
```

Output: *newitemsFruitsVegetablesDrink*

I instead want this,

- Fruits
- Vegetables
- Drink

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm curious: why do you want this behavior? It's much harder to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter% don't use @ for commands intended for document use....



\newcommand\@newitems{\begin{itemize}\@itemsi}


\def\@itemsi#1{%
  \ifx\stopitems#1%
    \end{itemize}\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \item#1\expandafter
  \fi
  \@itemsi}


This is the output I'm getting using this code

\@newitems
{Fruits}
{Vegetables}
{Drink}
\stopitems

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's pretty concise. Though since I'm a bit new to LaTeX can you explain what \expandafter does here? I know it takes the token after the next one but it's not clear to me how that's used here

Comment: @MilapSheth see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107753/why-the-expandafter-firstoftwo-idiom/

Answer (score 4):

#### Recursive Approach

See also the giggles at the bottom for a generic implementation. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\quark_new:N \StopItems

\cs_new:Nn \milap_new_items: { \begin{itemize} \milap_next_item:n }
\cs_new:Nn \milap_next_item:n {
  \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {\StopItems}
    { \end{itemize} }
    { \item #1 \milap_next_item:n }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \NewItems { } {
  \milap_new_items:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\NewItems
  {hello}
  {there}
  {world}
\StopItems
\end{document}
```

#### Idiomatic `expl3` (in my opinion)

Using `xparse` to grab all the arguments and `expl3` to work with them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \NewItems { u{\StopItems} } {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \item ##1 }
  \end{itemize}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\NewItems
  {hello}
  {world}
\StopItems
\end{document}
```

#### Comma-Separated List

For completion :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \NewItems { m } {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \item ##1 }
  \end{itemize}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\NewItems{hello,world}
\end{document}
```

#### Giggles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\quark_new:N \StopItems

\cs_new:Nn \milap_new_items:nn { \begin{#1} \milap_next_item:nnn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Nn \milap_next_item:nnn {
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF {#3} {\StopItems}
    { \end{#1} }
    { \item #3 \milap_next_item:nnn {#1} {#2} }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \NewItems { O{itemize} O{\item} } {
  \milap_new_items:nn {#1} {#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\NewItems[enumerate]
  {hello}
  {there}
  {world}
\StopItems
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\tl_if_eq:nnTF`, shouldn't it? Also `\StopItems` should probably be defined as a quark: `\quark_new:N \StopItems`

Comment: @egreg Hmm, yes it should; I must have gotten a little too happy with my shift key :) And you're absolutely right! `\StopItems` is definitely a quark here.

Comment: @egreg Is it appropriate to define `\StopItems` as a quark when it's used in a `u`-type `xparse` argspec?

Comment: In the case of a delimiter it's irrelevant: it can even be undefined.

Comment: @egreg Given how I think `u` is implemented, that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for writing all the different methods. I wasn't aware about the xparse package. Can you please explain what \cs_new and \tl_if_eq commands do?

Comment: @MilapSheth `xparse` is great :) Read up on `texdoc xparse` for more goodies. As for the other things, I'll refer you to `texdoc interface3` for the full documentation, but `\cs_new:` and `\tl_if_eq:` are `expl3` functions. `expl3` is the (very well-organized) programming layer with which LaTeX3 is being built. The two functions correspond roughly to `\def` and `\ifx`, respectively. Note that everything after the `:` is part of the function name, too. `expl3` has a different syntax to it, toggled with `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`Off` (analogous to `\makeatother`/`letter`).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [iterate over commaseparated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list/159132#159132)

Add this to your preamble and call inside document with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\makeitemize[1]{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \forcsvlist{\makeitemize@item}{#1}
  \end{itemize}
}
\newcommand\makeitemize@item[1]{\item #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeitemize{A,B,C} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution do not work in a simple article document like `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}` Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. I have corrected my answer and learned, to test code bevor submit to the community. This will never happen again.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger thanks for updating (original comment deleted)