# ampersand "&" causes if-else-fi to fail

Tags: tables, conditionals

I encountered a very strange problem today.

I want to fill tables with automatic generated data.  Hence, I designed a macro, which takes four arguments (one being optional).  Arguments No. 1 and 4 are allowed to be empty, therefore I put an `\ifx#1\@empty` test into my code.

This is my macro in the first version:

```latex
\newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
  #2&#3&
  \def\@rzid{#4}\ifx\@rzid\@empty\relax ./. \else \texttt{\@rzid}\fi&
  \def\@ldap{#1}\ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax
    yes
  \else
    & no
  \fi%
  \\%
}
```

I was very surprised to find, that LaTeX didn't compile.  This was the result:

> ! Extra \fi.
>       \\admin ...ldap @empty \relax yes \else & no \fi
>                                                         \\
>       ! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 51.
>       < inserted text>
>       \fi

After two hours fiddling, I found out, that the ampersand causes all the trouble.  This macro works without LaTeX throwing an error:

```latex
\newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
  #2&#3&
  \def\@rzid{#4}\ifx\@rzid\@empty\relax ./. \else \texttt{\@rzid}\fi&
  \def\@ldap{#1}\ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax
    yes
  \else 
    no
  \fi%
  \\%
}
```

The disadvantage is, that the word "No" is now standing in the wrong column. :-(  My MWA (Minimal Work Around) is now as follows, but I'd like to know, what went wrong and how to avoid the additional if-clause I came up with.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% This did not work due to the "&".  Removing the ampersand will get
%% the macro working, but than the word "No" from the ifclause will be
%% printed in the wrong column.
% \newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
%   #2&#3&
%   \def\@rzid{#4}\ifx\@rzid\@empty\relax ./. \else \texttt{\@rzid}\fi&
%   \def\@ldap{#1}\ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax
%     yes
%   %% The error starts here.  Comment out the next two lines, and the
%   %% error vanishes.  Remove the ampersand & and its also gone!
%   \else
%     & no
%   %% This would work
%   % \else 
%   %   no
%   \fi%
%   \\%
% }

%% Now: this works, but you have to have an extra if-clause!
\newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
  #2&#3&%
  \def\@rzid{#4}\ifx\@rzid\@empty\relax ./. \else \@rzid\fi&%
  \def\@ldap{#1}\ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax
    Yes
  \fi
  &
  \newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
  #2&#3&%
  \def\@rzid{#4}\ifx\@rzid\@empty\relax ./. \else \@rzid\fi&%
  \def\@ldap{#1}\ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax
    Yes
  \fi
  &
  \ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax\else
    No
  \fi%
  \\%
\def\@ldap{#1}\ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax\else
    No
  \fi%
  \\%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lllcc@{}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Anwender}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{RZ-ID}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{LDAP} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Vorname}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nachname}
    &
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{No} \\
    \hline
    \admin{First}{Lastname}{fl19}
    \admin{Some}{Othername}{so97}
    \admin[false]{Not}{Listed}{}
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

PS.: This is a minimal example.  In my real document, the macro is way more elaborative, as I added a lot more info to the second-last and last column.  Therefore, a suggestion, to use  `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}` or `\multicolumn{2}{c}{NO}`, spanning the last two columns to avoid the ampersand, is no option to me.

Comment: A conditional cannot straddle alignment cells.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in your actual MWA (I like that! `:-D`) you are getting

[image]

which probably isn't the intended result. The reason behind it is the same as the reason why your first solution fails: cells are groups, and your `\def\@ldap` is restricted to the fourth column. You should use `\gdef`instead to have it working.

Personally I see no point in avoiding the double `\if` at all costs but this would be a possible way

```
\newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
  #2&#3&%
  \def\@rzid{#4}\ifx\@rzid\@empty\relax ./. \else \@rzid\fi &
  \def\@ldap{#1}%
  \ifx\@ldap\@empty\relax % I prefer \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     \def\@tempa{\textcolor{green}{\ding{51}}&}%
  \else
     \def\@tempa{&\textcolor{red}{\ding{55}}}%
  \fi
  \@tempa
  \\
}
```

[image]

Basically, the `\if` just sets the definition of`\@tempa`, which is expanded only after the `\if` has been worked out.

Comment: Very cool and helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Conditionals cannot straddle alignment cells, but you can remove the conditional before issuing `&`; the technique uses `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`. See [Why the \expandafter\@firstoftwo idiom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107753/4427)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\admin}[4][]{%
  #2&#3&%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax
    ./.%
  \else
    #4%
  \fi&%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {Yes}{&No}%
  \\%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lllcc@{}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Anwender}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{RZ-ID}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{LDAP} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Vorname}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nachname}
    &
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{No} \\
    \hline
    \admin{First}{Lastname}{fl19}
    \admin{Some}{Othername}{so97}
    \admin[false]{Not}{Listed}{}
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I also removed the two auxiliary macros, preferring a different safe test for emptiness.

[image]