# \href macro in \section conflicts with local hyperref linking in ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, links

If I have a section like so

```
\section{Section 1}
```

then in the ToC, so long as I use the `hyperref` package, it is linked to that particular section. However, if I use an href tag as the section name,like so

```
\section{\href{http://www.google.com}{Section 1}}
```

In the ToC it goes directly to google.com (not what I want) instead of Section 1 (what I want). Is there any way to have it such that when I click on the Section title, it goes to the link, but when I click on the section in the ToC it goes to the Section (and not the link)?

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, 
   linkcolor=[rgb]{0.192157,0.309804,0.309804},
   urlcolor=cyan, 
   citecolor=blue}

\newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\xspace}

\begin{document}
   \title{Minimal \latex\ Example}
   \date{}
   \vspace{65 mm}
   \author{Julius Caesar}

   \maketitle

   \clearpage

   \tableofcontents

   \clearpage

   \section{Section 1}
   \label{sec:one}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

   \section{\href{http://www.google.com}{Section 2}}
   \label{sec:two}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum


\end{document}
```

Comment: What should happen to the link in chapter marks ([“running head”](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9137863#9137863)) in for example the `book` class?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed once you know that each heading command takes an optional argument for the `toc`.

In your case, you can use, for example,

```
   \section[Section 2 in toc]{\href{http://www.google.com}{Section 2}}
```

Here's a complete minimal working example (MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, 
   linkcolor=[rgb]{0.192157,0.309804,0.309804},
   urlcolor=cyan, 
   citecolor=blue}


\begin{document}
   \title{Minimal Example}
   \author{Julius Caesar}

   \maketitle

   \clearpage

   \tableofcontents

   \clearpage

   \section{Section 1}
   \label{sec:one}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

   \section[Section 2 in toc]{\href{http://www.google.com}{Section 2}}
   \label{sec:two}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum


\end{document}
%
```

Answer (score 3):

[cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110580/16595)’ answer is the first thing I thought of too. But it is a rather manual solution.

By `\let`tting `\href` to `\@secondoftwo` its definition changes to

```
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2}
```

(which we also could have done without any actual knowledge of `\@secondoftwo`).

The `.toc` file and the Table of Contents still contain `\href{www.google.com}{Section 2}` but `\href` then expands to `Section 2`, its second argument.

Enclosing this in `\begingroup … \endgroup` keeps the change to `\href` local to `\killHref`. (There are other ways to restore the original definition of `\href` without the use of this grouping, though.)

---

If the editor of your choice gives you trouble, replace

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\killHref}[1]{\begingroup\let\href\@secondoftwo#1\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

with

```
\newcommand*{\killHref}[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand{\href}[2]{##2}#1\endgroup}
```

#### References

- [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/16595)
- [What do `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, 
   linkcolor=[rgb]{0.192157,0.309804,0.309804},
   urlcolor=cyan, 
   citecolor=blue}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\killHref}[1]{\begingroup\let\href\@secondoftwo#1\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \killHref{\tableofcontents}
    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{\href{http://www.google.com}{Section 2}}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Can you briefly describe what `\makeatletter\let\href\@secondoftwo` does. Thank You

Comment: I like your solution more cmhughes', but it gives me the following error in vim `Do not use @ in LaTeX macro names. "\@secondoftwo".

Comment: @puk Erm, yes, well … The `@` is usually not a letter that is allowed in macro names, hence the `\makeatletter` (see reference). If you want to satisfy your editor, use `\newcommand*{\killHref}[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand{\href}[2]{##2}#1\endgroup}` instead, though you may ignore this warning (not an error per se).

Comment: What line would I substitute with that?

Comment: @puk I have updated the answer with a hopefully good explanation what to substitute.