# Conditional based on packageoption

Tags: macros, conditionals, package-options

I added a counter to the `todonotes` packages `\todo` so I could display the total number of todos I have left. However I also enjoy working with the package option disabled. Therefore I would like to wrap the part where I typeset the counter in a conditional that is only executed when the packageoption `disable` is NOT given. However I do not know how I can access this package option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}                        %properly rename protected macros
\usepackage{totcount}                           %counter totals before last increment
\usepackage{xcolor}                             %for the red text (will be loaded by todonotes but for completness)
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}                           %make links in listoftodos clickable

\newtotcounter{todocounter}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldTodo}{\todo} %avoid endless recursion be redefining \todo as \todo+x
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\stepcounter{todocounter}\oldTodo[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\LARGE{\textcolor{red}{\total{todocounter} todos left}} %if wrap this line
\todo{1}

later
\todo{some more}
\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cgnieder: you "awnsered" quite often by leaving a key comment, this always makes me think if you just want me to close/remove the question due to beeing to localized or similar. But since you bothered to give a nice detailed awnser I wonder why you do this. (I hope this does not sound offensive, if it should, it is not meant that way)

Comment: I sometimes do that when I'm not sure if my answer is the best way or when the question lacks an MWE or if I don't have the time to compose a full answer or ... it doesn't mean much :)

Comment: Also see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disable` option sets `\@todonotes@disabledtrue`, i.e., a conditional that can be tested with

```
\if@todonotes@disabled
  ...
\else
  ...
\fi
```

The code below wraps this in a command `\iftodonotes{<true>}{<false>}` which is more convenient to use as it doesn't contain `@` as a letter.

BTW: `\LARGE` does *not* take an argument but is a font property switch. Instead of `\LARGE{...}` you should write `{\LARGE ...}` (i.e., place the call in a group) otherwise following text will also be `\LARGE` until you set another size again.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtotcounter{todocounter}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldTodo}{\todo}
\makeatletter
% this defines \iftodonotes{<true>}{<false>}
\newcommand*\iftodonotes{%
  \if@todonotes@disabled
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\stepcounter{todocounter}\oldTodo[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\iftodonotes
  {{\LARGE\textcolor{red}{\total{todocounter} todos left}}}
  {}

\todo{1} foo

later \todo{some more}

\listoftodos

\end{document}
```

Comment: For those that don't know about `\@secondoftwo` like me: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/19326. If I need that `if` only once would there be any reason against simply using the part inside the `newcommand` definition directly?

Comment: You can of course use `\if@todonotes@disabled` directly (you'd have to make `@` at letter before you use it and should make it other again afterwards). However, I think it's much cleaner to define a new command with a LaTeX syntax. And who knows: maybe you find out later that there are more places where you want to use it.