# Write "conditionnally" rows of a tabular with spreadtab

Tags: tables, spreadtab

I'm writing a tabular using the spreadtab package for some calculus. I want to write it's rows only under a certain condition, i.e. to test in each of its rows if the condition is true, and then write this row, and not write the row it if the condition is false. All is ok when I do this in a tabular environment, like in this example, where the line of 3 is not written, because '1=2' is false:

```
Tabular\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1&1         \\  \hline
\ifnum 1=1 2&2 \fi \\ \hline
\ifnum 1=2 3&3 \\ \hline\fi 
\ifnum 1=1 4&4 \fi \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\\ 
End of Tabular
```

which compiles well like this:
[image]
Now if I insert the same tabular in a spreadtab environment, like in this macro:

```
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|}}
\hline
1&1\\
\ifnum 1=1 2&2 \fi \\ \hline
\ifnum 1=2 3&3 \\ \hline\fi 
\ifnum 1=1 4&4 \fi \\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
```

The program doesn't compile and I have this message of error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> 2 \fi \@@nil
&
l.26 ^^I\end{spreadtab}
```

what is the problem in my program and how can I repair it ? Thank you

Comment: The problem with tabular is that it uses its own parser.  If it is simple enough, you can replace tabular with lots of \makebox'es.

Comment: The problem is that it's not simple but I have simplified it. I use this test in statistical calculus

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put only text in a cell with `spreadtab` you simply place
somewhere in the cell the character `@`, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131265/defining-tabular-rows-with-macros-using-ifnum-leads-to-incomplete-ifnum) show how you can skip `&` inside the conditional.

The command `\condRow` with three arguments test if the first argument is equal to 1, the first and second cells of tabular will be the second and third argument of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\condRow}[3]{\ifnum \numexpr#1\relax=1  #2\uppercase{&}#3\\\fi 
\ifnum \numexpr#1\relax=1 \hline\fi}


\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|}}
\hline
1&1\\ \hline
@\condRow{1}{34}{202}
3&3\\ \hline 
4&4\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This seems good for simple tests and literal expressions using the @ character. But I have some calculation in my cells ever my condition is true

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna People can't read your mind.

Comment: Hello @egreg I don't understand.. what do you call "my mind' ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Your question doesn't mention you want to do computations in the omitted cells

Comment: I want to compute percentile and my test is on when the cumulated frequency is greater then the order of the percentile, and then do (and write !) the computation of this percentile, else do nothing...

Comment: You can update your question or ask new  which indicate  what you want more.