# Why is \@secondoftwo used in this example?

Tags: macros, latex-base

I have been studying the code from this [TUGboat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents30-1.html) by Joseph Wright and Christian Feurersänger (Volume 30, 2009, No. 1) explaining key-value techniques. I understand the use of `\expandafter\@firstofone` in the first two user macros but I can't understand where the second argument referenced by `\@secondoftwo` comes from in the third user macro. Is it the name of the desired color passed to the `colour` option?

I understand how the expansion works here. I don’t understand exactly why `\@secondoftwo` is used rather than `\@firstofone`. The question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21263/218142 makes the distinction very clear, but I can’t see the distinction in this case.

Here is the (slightly edited by me) MWE package file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{xmph}[2008/03/17 v1.0 Extended emph] 
\RequirePackage{color,kvoptions} 
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=xmph,
  prefix=xmph@
}%
\DeclareBoolOption{useitalic}
\DeclareBoolOption{usebold}
\DeclareBoolOption{usecolour}
\DeclareBoolOption{usecolor}
\let\KV@xmph@usecolor
  \KV@xmph@usecolour
\DeclareStringOption{colour}
\define@key{xmph}{color}{\setkeys{xmph}{colour=#1}}
\DeclareVoidOption{inactive}{%
  \PackageInfo{xmph}{Package inactive}%
  \AtEndOfPackage{\let\xmph\emph}%
}%
\setkeys{xmph}{useitalic,colour=red}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{xmph}
\define@key{xmph}{inactive}{%
  \PackageInfo{xmph}{Package inactive}
  \let\xmph\emph
}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DisableKeyvalOption[action=warning,package=xmph]{xmph}{inactive}
}%
\newcommand*{\xmphsetup}{%
  \setkeys{xmph}%
}%

\newcommand*{\xmph}[1]{%
  \xmph@emph{%
    \xmph@bold{%
      {%
        \xmph@colourtext{#1}
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand*{\xmph@emph}{%
  \ifxmph@useitalic 
    \expandafter\emph
  \else 
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}%
\newcommand*{\xmph@bold}{%
  \ifxmph@usebold 
    \expandafter\textbf
  \else 
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}%
\newcommand*{\xmph@colourtext}{%
  \ifxmph@usecolour 
    \expandafter\textcolor
  \else 
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\xmph@colour}
}%
```

And here is the (again, slightly edited) MWE document using the package file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmkjoe
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usecolour,color=blue,usebold]{xmph}
%\xmphsetup{inactive}

\begin{document}
Some text \xmph{text}
  
\xmphsetup{usecolor=false,usebold=false,useitalic=false}%
\xmph{more text}

\xmphsetup{usecolor=true,color=cyan,usebold=false,useitalic=true}%
\xmph{more text}
  
\xmphsetup{usecolor=false,usebold=false,useitalic=false}%
\xmph{even more text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to get effectively `\textcolor{\xmph@colour}<stuff>` or just `<stuff>`, and do not want to drown in `\expandafter`s, so you decide to skip over `{\xmph@colour}` if you just want to have `<stuff>`.

Comment: That makes sense. Is the second argument the desired color?

Comment: How would I know which color you desire? ;-)

Comment: What's confusing me is that `\xmph` is defined with one parameter but the use of `\@secondoftwo` implies a second parameter and I can't see where it comes from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the call `\xmph{foo} abc`. This translates into

```
\xmph@emph{\xmph@bold{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }}} abc
```

according to your code. Now `\xmph@emph` is expanded. This turns into

```
\ifxmph@useitalic\expandafter\emph\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi⮐
{\xmph@bold{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }}} abc
```

(the symbol `⮐` denotes continuation). According to the truth value of `\ifxmph@useitalic`, this becomes either

```
\emph{\xmph@bold{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }}} abc
```

or

```
\@firstofone{\xmph@bold{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }}} abc
```

The latter just strips the braces off the argument and I'll follow this case for simplicity. We get

```
\xmph@bold{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }} abc
```

and this turns into

```
\ifxmph@usebold\expandafter\textbf\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi⮐
\xmph@bold{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }} abc
```

Again, depending on the truth value of `\ifxmph@usebold` we get either

```
\textbf{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }} abc
```

or

```
\@firstofone{{\xmph@colourtext{foo} }} abc
```

Let's follow the latter case, getting

```
{\xmph@colourtext{foo} } abc
```

The opening brace is digested, opening a group; then we obtain

```
\ifxmph@usecolour\expandafter\textcolor\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi⮐
{\xmph@colour} {foo} } abc
```

Depending on the value of `\ifxmph@usecolour` we get either

```
\textcolor{\xmph@colour} {foo} } abc
```

or

```
\@secondoftwo{\xmph@colour} {foo} } abc
```

Now you should clearly see why `\@secondoftwo` is necessary, so the color part is removed from the input stream. The space in the middle is removed by rule, because `\@secondoftwo` takes two undelimited arguments (and `\textcolor` eventually calls a macro taking two arguments as well).

Now `foo` is printed (colored or not), the following space is printed, the group that had been opened is closed, another space is printed and processing continues from `abc`.

The cases when `\emph` and `\textbf` are used just add some complications which are irrelevant as far as understanding `\@secondoftwo` is concerned.

You see that you have two points that should be fixed: the spurious spaces and the useless group. Try the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usecolour,color=blue,usebold]{xmph}
%\xmphsetup{inactive}

\begin{document}

Some text \emph{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{text}}} some text

Some text \xmph{text} some text
  
\xmphsetup{usecolor=false,usebold=false,useitalic=false}

\xmph{more text} some text

\xmphsetup{usecolor=true,color=cyan,usebold=false,useitalic=true}

\xmph{more text} some text
  
\xmphsetup{usecolor=false,usebold=false,useitalic=false}

\xmph{even more text} some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

and you'll see the spurious space. Fix the missing `%` tokens (and getting rid of the unneeded ones) and remove the useless group:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{xmph}[2008/03/17 v1.0 Extended emph] 
\RequirePackage{color,kvoptions} 
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=xmph,
  prefix=xmph@
}
\DeclareBoolOption{useitalic}
\DeclareBoolOption{usebold}
\DeclareBoolOption{usecolour}
\DeclareBoolOption{usecolor}
\let\KV@xmph@usecolor\KV@xmph@usecolour
\DeclareStringOption{colour}
\define@key{xmph}{color}{\setkeys{xmph}{colour=#1}}
\DeclareVoidOption{inactive}{%
  \PackageInfo{xmph}{Package inactive}%
  \AtEndOfPackage{\let\xmph\emph}%
}
\setkeys{xmph}{useitalic,colour=red}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{xmph}
\define@key{xmph}{inactive}{%
  \PackageInfo{xmph}{Package inactive}%
  \let\xmph\emph
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DisableKeyvalOption[action=warning,package=xmph]{xmph}{inactive}%
}
\newcommand*{\xmphsetup}{%
  \setkeys{xmph}%
}

\newcommand*{\xmph}[1]{%
  \xmph@emph{%
    \xmph@bold{%
      \xmph@colourtext{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\xmph@emph}{%
  \ifxmph@useitalic 
    \expandafter\emph
  \else 
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\xmph@bold}{%
  \ifxmph@usebold 
    \expandafter\textbf
  \else 
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\xmph@colourtext}{%
  \ifxmph@usecolour 
    \expandafter\textcolor
  \else 
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\xmph@colour}%
}
```

Now the same input file as before yields

[image]

---

Here is an implementation with `expl3`. There is no `\expandafter` and the coding is much more straightforward.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{xmph}[2008/03/17 v1.0 Extended emph]
\RequirePackage{expl3,xparse,l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% define the keys
\keys_define:nn { xmph }
 {
  useitalic .bool_set:N = \l_xmph_italic_bool,
  useitalic .default:n = true,
  usebold   .bool_set:N = \l_xmph_bold_bool,
  usebold   .default:n = true,
  usecolour .bool_set:N = \l_xmph_colour_bool,
  usecolour .default:n = true,
  usecolor  .bool_set:N = \l_xmph_colour_bool,
  usecolor  .default:n = true,
  colour    .tl_set:N = \l_xmph_colour_tl,
  color     .tl_set:N = \l_xmph_colour_tl,
  inactive  .code:n = \__xmph_inactivate:,
  inactive  .value_forbidden:n = true,
 }

% we don't want to set inactive in the document
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \keys_define:nn { xmph }
   {
    inactive .code:n = \PackageWarning{xmph}{Disabled~option},
   }
 }

% process the package keys
\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { xmph }

%%% user level commands

\NewDocumentCommand{\xmphsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { xmph } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\xmph}{m}
 {
  \xmph_emph:n { \xmph_bold:n { \xmph_colour:n { #1 } } }
 }

%%% internal functions

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__xmph_inactivate:
 {
  \PackageInfo{xmph}{Package~inactive}
  \AtBeginDocument{\cs_set_eq:NN \xmph \emph}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xmph_emph:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_xmph_italic_bool { \emph { #1 } } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xmph_bold:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_xmph_bold_bool { \textbf { #1 } } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xmph_colour:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_xmph_colour_bool { \textcolor { \l_xmph_colour_tl } { #1 } } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: AHA! My conceptual block was in thinking that `\@firstofone` and `\@secondoftwo` and such could only be used on parameters `#1` or `#2` etc. and not on general tokens. That was my problem and you cleared it up.

Answer (score 4):

You should follow the expansion in order to understand the use of `\@secondoftwo`. Consider a call to

```
\xmph{<stuff>}
```

`\xmph` takes a single argument, based on its definition, and passes that on directly to `\xmph@colourtext{#1}`.

Now, `\xmph@colourtext` is defined to take no argument. So, with the `usecolor` option set to `true`,

```
\ifxmph@usecolour 
  \expandafter\textcolor
\else 
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
```

expands to `\textcolor`. With `\usecolor=false`, it expands to `\@secondoftwo`. Before closing, `\xmph@colourtext` inserts `{\xmph@colour}` into the input stread, effectively turning `\xmph@colourtext{<stuff>}` into `\textcolor{\xmph@colour}{<stuff>}` or `\@secondoftwo{\xmph@colour}{<stuff>}`.

So, the `\@secondoftwo` skips the reference to colour (`\xmph@colour`) and just prints `<stuff>`.

Comment: My problem was not recognizing that `\@secondoftwo` can be used on things other than arguments like `#1` and `#2`.

Answer (score 2):

As written in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576211/why-is-secondoftwo-used-in-this-example/576223#comment1450920_576211), and copied by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), this is to skip over `{\xmph@colour}`. That is, you want to get effectively \textcolor{\xmph@colour} or just , and do not want to drown in \expandafters, so you decide to skip over {\xmph@colour} if you just want to have .

In other words, when you call

```
\xmph{<stuff>}
```

there are two cases. In case `\ifxmph@usecolour` is true, you get

```
\textcolor{\xmph@colour}<stuff>
```

On the other hand, if `\ifxmph@usecolour`, you get `\@secondoftwo{\xmph@colour}{<stuff>}`, which is just `{<stuff>}`.

Comment: Let me approach this differently. What if `\@firstofone` had been used instead of `\@secondoftwo`. Would the code work the same way? I understand the expansion.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL You could have moved `{\xmph@colour}` right after `\textcolor` but then you would have to start an orgy of `\expandafter`s to get after `{`, `\xmph@colour` and `}`. This is what I meant by drowning in `\expandafter`.

Comment: Okay now your explanation makes sense. I thought `\@firstofone` and `\@secondoftwo` were tied to arguments like `#1` and `#2`. That was my problem.