# Define a macro whose name depends on a condition

Tags: macros, conditionals

I tried the following three ways to give value(here is `aaa`) to a macro whose name depends on a condition.

Only the third one works. However, the value `aaa` has to be written twice. If the value is very long, this would be very annoying.

Any better way?

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
Method 1:
% \expandafter\def\ifnum 5>4 \aaa\else\bbb\fi{aaa}
% \aaa
Method 2:
% \ifnum 5>4\def\aaa\else\def\bbb\fi{aaa}
% \aaa
Method 3:
\ifnum 5>4\def\aaa{aaa}\else\def\bbb{aaa}\fi
\aaa
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXbook, Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros) says:

> - Conditionals. When an `\if...` is expanded, TeX reads ahead as far as necessary to determine whether the condition is true or false; and if false, it skips ahead (keeping track of `\if...\fi` nesting) until finding the `\else`, `\or`, or `\fi` that ends the skipped text. Similarly, when `\else`, `\or`, or `\fi` is expanded, TeX reads to the end of any text that ought to be skipped. The "expansion" of a conditional is empty. (Conditionals always reduce the number of tokens that are seen by later stages of the digestive process, while macros usually increase the number of tokens.)

```
% Here toplevel-expansion of \ifnum ends before the 1st token of the true-branch/\if..-branch.
% \expandafter..\expandafter in the true-branch/\if..-branch is used to make the entire \else..\fi-branch go away:

\ifnum 5>4 \expandafter\def\expandafter\aaa\else
           \expandafter\def\expandafter\bbb\fi{aaa}%

\expandafter\show\ifnum 5>4 \aaa\else\bbb\fi

% Here toplevel-expansion of \ifnum ends before the 1st token of the false-branch/\else..-branch.
% \expandafter..\expandafter in the false-branch/\else..-branch is used to make the token `\fi` go away:

\ifnum 5>5 \expandafter\def\expandafter\aaa\else
           \expandafter\def\expandafter\bbb\fi{aaa}%

\expandafter\show\ifnum 5>5 \aaa\else\bbb\fi

\csname bye\endcsname
\stop
```

---

*While this answer is intended to exhibit expansion-steps with  `\if..\else..\fi`-expressions, which rather indicates a didactic objective, the answers of [wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634622/118714) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634552/118714), imho, show best how to actually handle things in practice.*

Answer (score 5):

Conditionally do `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conditionalnewcommand}[3]{%
  % #1 = test, #2 = name for true, #3 = name for false
  #1\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\newcommand#2}{\newcommand#3}%
}
\makeatother

\conditionalnewcommand{\ifnum5>4}{\aaa}{\bbb}{this is aaa}
\conditionalnewcommand{\ifnum3>4}{\aaa}{\bbb}{this is bbb}

\begin{document}

\aaa

\bbb

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if this is package code and the command name depends on some switch, say `\ifpackage@foo`, you can do

```
\newcommand\package@command{whatever}
\@onlypreamble\package@command
\ifpackage@foo
  \@ifdefinable{\aaa}{\let\aaa\package@command}
\else
  \@ifdefinable{\bbb}{\let\bbb\package@command}
\fi
```

Comment: Many thanks @egreg! And what's the meaning of `@firstoftwo` and `@sencondoftwo`? And where do they come from?

Comment: @lyl You can find the description on the site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/4427

Answer (score 4):

I would use `\csname ...\endcsname` pair and `\if` conditional inside them:

```
\expandafter \def \csname \ifnum 4>5 aaa\else bbb\fi \endcsname {...}
```

Your experiments are bad because the `\if` conditional evaluates the condition but does not closes whole construction, i.e. `\else` and `\fi` remains when `\def` started.