# ifcase command that changes color does not work

Tags: macros, pdftex, color, conditionals, expandafter

I am creating a handout with a command that hides the answers for students and reveals the answers for instructors. I defined a new command `invisible` that takes a bool and text. If `0`, the text should be untouched. If `1`, the text should be printed in white, making it invisible on paper. However in this example the text is printed regardless of the bool. I created another command `altinvisible` where the text is not a parameter. It did not solve the problem. What is wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\invisible}[2]{\ifcase#1\or\expandafter\textcolor{white}\fi{#2}}
\newcommand{\altinvisible}[1]{\ifcase#1\or\expandafter\textcolor{white}\fi}

\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

{3.14}

\textcolor{white}{3.14}

\invisible{0}{3.14}

\invisible{1}{3.14}

\altinvisible{0}{3.14}

\altinvisible{1}{3.14}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't fully understand how TeX's macros and primitives (such as `\expandafter` in this case) work, I recommend writing easy-to-understand macros that does not use them (see the modified `\invisible` macro as in my answer) (possibly at the cost of slightly slower compilation).

If you want to learn, there are a few ways. See `\altinvisible` and `\altbinvisible` macros below.

Learning material:

- [What do \@firstoftwo and \@secondoftwo do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/250119)
- TeXbook/TeX by Topic (to read up on `\expandafter`)
- https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_does_%5Cexpandafter_work%3A_An_introduction_to_TeX_tokens
- [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/250119)

tl;dr in this case, the bug is that you can clearly see the `\expandafter` cannot be used to execute the `\fi` early if there's more than one token between the `\expandafter` and the `\fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\textcolorwhite}{\textcolor{white}}
\newcommand{\invisible}[2]{\ifcase#1 #2\or\textcolor{white}{#2}\fi}
\newcommand{\altinvisible}[1]{\ifcase#1\or\expandafter\textcolorwhite\fi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\altbinvisible}[1]{\ifcase#1\or\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother

\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

visible: {3.14}

invisible: \textcolor{white}{3.14}

visible: \invisible{0}{3.14}

invisible: \invisible{1}{3.14}

visible: \altinvisible{0}{3.14}

visible: \altbinvisible{0}{3.14}

invisible: \altinvisible{1}{3.14}

invisible: \altbinvisible{1}{3.14}

\end{document}
```