# How is \iffalse ... \fi handled?

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

Let's have a look at the example:

```
Some text.
\iffalse
Nothing to print.
\fi
Further text.
```

I would expect that this is handled like

```
Some text.

Further text.
```

because the system simply removes the part between `\iffalse`and `\fi`. But when you test it, in the resulting pdf you read `Some text. Further text.` in the same line. So this suggests that the text is handled like

```
Some text.
Further text.
```

Can somebody explain why we lose one linebreak?

Comment: To answer the question in title [macros - What do \@firstoftwo and \@secondoftwo do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do) , but the actual reason here has something to do with tokenization of characters of catcode end of line. (low level details are in e.g. TeXbook.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whitespaces (but not empty lines, because they are `\par`) after macros, primitives etc. are always ignored (they delimit the macro name). A end of line is just a whitespace. So you not just have to remove everything from `\iffalse` until the end of `\fi`, but also the whitespaces (end-of-line) after `\fi` and you'll get:

```
Some text.
Further text.
```

In in other words: Because end-of-line is just a whitespace, your original code is the same like

```
Some text. \iffalse Nothing to print. \fi Further text.
```

and this expands to:

```
Some text. Further text.
```

Note: The space after “`text.`” is not the space from behind `\fi`, it is the space from before `\iffalse`.

Note: In previous versions of the answer I wrote “is the same like” instead of “expands to”, but this is not really correct, because TeX really scans and parses the `\iffalse`, so a line with `\iffalse` is never an empty line in sense of TeX. Additionally the special handling of `\if…` happens: TeX reads the following without expanding until either `\else` or `\fi` is found. And if while this reading another TeX `\if…` (e.g., `\iftrue`, `\iffalse`, `\ifcase`, `\ifx`, `\ifcsname`, `\if` etc.) is found, it is also read until the corresponding `\fi`.

Comment: How many whitespaces after a `\fi` are ignored? If I add a further newline after `\fi` one sees a linebreak in the pdf document. However, if I put a space after `\fi` and then a newline I don't see a newline in the pdf document. In both cases it are two whitespaces. I don't understand the logic.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Empty lines are `\par` and therefore not ignored. This is nothing special for `\if…\fi` but the same for other commands like `\relax`.

Comment: Depends on your exact definition of "whitespace". "Characters with whitespace catcode before tokenization" are ignored, but "whitespace token" certainly is not. In that sense the first sentence is a bit confusing because the "whitespace" part refers to the characters but the part in the parentheses refer to the tokens.