# How to make LaTeX ignore the contents of an environment?

Tags: environments, conditionals

I would like to make a `\todo` command and environment whose behavior changes depending whether I define a command `\showtodos`. A basic `\todo` command is simple to write:

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\showtodos}}{
  \newcommand{\todo}[1]{}
}{
  \newcommand{\todo}[1]{#1}
}
```

Essentially, I would like to hide the content of the `\todo` command unless `\showtodos` is defined. My question is how to write an environment which does the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A hint: If you indent lines of code by 4 spaces, they will auto-format nicely. And, by adding backticks, `, around LaTeX commands, they will also be offset visually for readers.

Comment: There is the [`todonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) package, which you might find useful. If you load it with the package option `disable` (`\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}`), nothing will be displayed. Otherwise, its `\todo{Rewrite this chapter}` macro works really well.

Answer (score 13):

There are quite a few packages that do what you want, which have been mentioned in the comments.

However, if you want your own solution, you can use the `comment` environment from the `verbatim` package to your advantage.

The solution below defines a `todo` environment that will only show its contents if `\showtodos` is defined; otherwise it puts `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` around the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}   % for the comment environment
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% if you want to see the todo
\newcommand{\showtodos}{show them}  % comment this line if you don't 
                                    % want to see todo environment

% the todo environment
\newenvironment{todo}%
        {%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\showtodos}}%
                    {\expandafter\comment}%
                    {}%
                    }%
         {%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\showtodos}}%
                    {\expandafter\endcomment}%
                    {}%
          }

\begin{document}

Outside of the the `todo' environment

\begin{todo}
 Here we are in the `todo' environment.
\end{todo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is the `\expandafter` necessary, please?

Comment: I suspect expandafter is actually unnecessary here (although not very sure if `ifthen` package does it correctly), it's only necessary if some primitive TeX conditional is used, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do/21263#21263

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic example using `\@ifundefined`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\todo}{%
  \@ifundefined{showtodo}{\relax}{%
    This is stuff to do.%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
1 \todo \par
2 \newcommand{\showtodo}{} \todo
\end{document}
```

Here is a basic example using a traditional `\newif` statement, as an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifshowtodocmd \showtodocmdfalse
\newcommand{\showtodo}{\showtodocmdtrue}
\newcommand{\todo}{%
  \ifshowtodocmd
    This is stuff to do.%
  \fi}
\begin{document}
1 \todo \par
2 \showtodo \todo
\end{document}
```

The same could be applied to environments. The [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) also provides a very rich set of macros to test for the existence of other macros or other conditioning commands in general.

For reference on command existence, read the TeX FAQ entry on [Is this command defined?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, you'll have to specify somewhere whether to enable or disable todos anyway, the need for a command like \enabletodos feels a bit artificial to me. You could just use something like

```
\newcommand\printTodo[1]{I still have to do #1}
\newcommand\todo[1]{\printTodo{#1}}
```

If you want to disable \todo, just replace the second line with

```
\newcommand\todo[1]{}
```

This leaves your "how to print todos" command invariant, and is basically equivalent to not specifying \showtodos. As a bonus, you can re-define the todo command anywhere, so you can easily switch the behavior throughout the document.