# How to turn off an environment (e.g. tikzpicture) for faster draft compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I'm currently writing my thesis and have been looking for ways to speed up compile time. I can shave off a lot of time by using draft mode so that images aren't processed, but I have several TikZ diagrams which also take some time to compile. Is there a way for me to put a switch in my header that can ignore processing the TikZ diagrams when I'm just checking my writing?

For example, I'd just like to 'turn off' the `tikzpicture` environment when compiling drafts.

Comment: I recommend the TikZ library `external`: [tag:tikz-external]

Comment: Maybe this answer is of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37945/9517

Comment: You might also consider putting your TikZ pictures in separate TeX files with the `standalone` document class, and then including the pdf files as graphics. That way, draft mode will automatically omit them.

Comment: This question is essentially answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60474/484

Comment: @CharlesStaats : About the `standalone` suggestion, I think it might cause issues if you are using cross-references in the tikz pictures.

Comment: @CharlesStaats : The other question is indeed an excellent suggestion. Whether it is or not a duplicate of this one depends on the meaning of "for example" here. Is the OP looking for a general answer, which would work for any environment, or specifically for tikz environments?

Comment: @T.Verron: First of all, the question is not an exact duplicate; it just so happens that the answer there applies here. Second, if you eliminate the lines about drawing a box in the answer there, it should be adaptable to "turn off" any environment.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for the possible redundancy!

Comment: Related: [Simple way to switch inline `asymptote` figures on and off](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111655/5764)

Comment: very related: [Draft mode for pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60434)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution that redefines the `tikzpicture` environment by conditionally wrapping a `comment` environment (from the `verbatim` package) around it. I've only tested it with `tikzpicture` but I think it could be easily adapted to any other environment.

Set the `\newif` called `\showtikz` to true (using `\showtikztrue`) or false (using `\showtikzfalse`) at the beginning of your document in order to show or hide all the `tikzpicture` environments in your document, respectively.

[This solution by cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37945/21891) to the question [How to make LaTeX ignore the contents of an environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37925/how-to-make-latex-ignore-the-contents-of-an-environment) was useful.

**EDIT**: I changed my `\newif`, originally `\hidetikz`, to new `\showtikz`; double negatives such as `\hidetikzfalse` are difficult to parse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}   % for the comment environment
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifshowtikz
\showtikztrue
%\showtikzfalse   % <---- comment/uncomment that line

\let\oldtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\let\oldendtikzpicture\endtikzpicture

\renewenvironment{tikzpicture}{%
    \ifshowtikz\expandafter\oldtikzpicture%
    \else\comment%   
    \fi
}{%
    \ifshowtikz\oldendtikzpicture%
    \else\endcomment%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \path[draw=red,fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If `\showtikz` is set to true, the output is:

[image]

If `\showtikz` is set to false, the output is:

[image]

Comment: If you want this to work when options are given to `\begin{tikzpicture}` (e.g. `[scale=2]`), you need to put an `\expandafter` between `\else` and `\oldtikzpicture` in your redefinition of `{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: What if the OP wants the rest of the formatting (paragraphing, pagination) to be independent of whether the picture is present/absent? Probably not what he needs, but makes the question harder. Then you'd need to know the size of the picture.

Comment: @EthanBolker Well, that's not what I understand the OP wants, so I didn't consider that possibility at all. I don't see how that could be easily done, though. The size of the picture depends on the `tikz` commands inside it, so you'd probably have to somehow draw the complete picture anyway in order to get the correct size. That would not speed up the compilation, as required by the OP.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Re: Ethan's question, indeed, this isn't relevant for my current workflow, but it's an interesting question as well. Thanks to all for the very helpful discussion, solution, and references.

Comment: It leaves the Caption (in this example caption is not there) intact. What if I want to removed the caption too?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111661/5764) in [Simple way to switch inline asymptote figures on and off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111655/5764) (with a slight modification), you can gobble the content of an environment using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ), and output whatever you want instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\newcounter{tikzfigcntr}
%\RenewEnviron{tikzpicture}[1][]{%
%  \par% New paragraph
%  \stepcounter{tikzfigcntr}% Step tikzfigcntr counter
%  This is \texttt{tikzpicture}~\thetikzfigcntr% Place appropriate text
%  \par% New paragraph
%}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \path[draw=red,fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the `tikzpicture` redefinition (and counter definition), the replacement text "This is `tikzpicture` `<num>`" is printed (where `<num>` is a counter representing the picture number). Replace this with whatever you want:

[image]

Comment: Does providing `\env@tikzpicture@save@env` and `\env@tikzpicture@process` have any effect in this?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman: There was a bug in [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) which required this to exist in order to `\RenewEnviron` an environment that wasn't originally defined with `\NewEnviron`. This was fixed in v0.3 (2015/05/04). I've updated the answer since it's not necessary anymore.