# Simple way to switch inline asymptote figures on and off

Tags: macros, graphics, conditionals, asymptote

I use the inline `asymptote` environment `\begin{asy}` to draw a lot of the figures in my papers. To those not familiar with `asymptote`, the [asymptote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/asymptote) package creates *.asy files for each of the asy environments in the document, so that if my document is `article.tex` running LaTeX will generate `article-1.asy`, `article-2.asy`, etc. Then you run `asymptote` (the program) to compile these into eps files `article-1.eps`, `article-2.eps`, etc. and the next time you run LaTeX it will include these graphics files where the corresponding asymptote environment was used.

However, this doesn't seem to be a standard package, so when I send the TeX file to arXiv or to a publisher I need to replace each `\begin{asy}...\end{asy}` with `\includegraphics{article-1}`, etc. Can anybody suggest a good way that I can make this switch back and forth easily by only changing one line? All my attempts have failed due to apparent quirks in how the `asymptote` package works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have a look at [asyfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/asyfig) package which does "read­ing Asymp­tote fig­ures from sep­a­rate `.asy` files, rather than within the doc­u­ment," very useful incase of a large doc­u­ments.

Comment: May be generate all figures in pdf from `fig.asy` files using `asy -f pdf *.asy` inside the figures folder(Linux).

Comment: @texenthusiast: Having the asymptote code in a separate file would definitely make switching more snappy. I don't see how your second suggestion is supposed to help. I already do that as part of the compilation process (but without `-f pdf`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{asymptote}% http://ctan.org/pkg/asymptote
\newenvironment{asy}{\par}{\par}% Fake asymptote package
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcounter{asyfigcntr}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{asy}{%
  \NewEnviron{asy}{%
    \par\stepcounter{asyfigcntr}%
    \includegraphics{\jobname-\theasyfigcntr}%
    \par%
  }
}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is some text.

\begin{asy}
Here is some \texttt{asy} code
\end{asy}

This is some more text.

\begin{asy}
Here is some more \texttt{asy} code.
\end{asy}

Here is some text again.
\end{document}
```

Since I'm unfamiliar with the interface of [`asymptote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/asymptote), I've created a "fake `asymptote` package" through the environment `asy`. If this environment exists (done by checking for the existence of `\asy`, since the `asy` environment is made up of `\asy` and `\endasy`, primitively speaking), then compilation continues as expected. If the environment does not exist, I create a new one that gobbles its contents (thanks to the collection capability supplied by the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)) and display the image given by `\jobname-\theasyfigcntr` (which expands to `<filename>-<num>`, where `<num>` is sequentially incremented).

When you comment out the "fake `asymptote` package", you get the following output:

[image]

The black boxes are from the `[demo]` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), which you should not use in your own document.

For practical purposes and to be feasible for usage in your case, the assumption is that you have at least one successful compile of your document under `asymptote` in order to produce the figures.

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks, and I've learned some new stuff (`environ`, `demo`) to boot.

Comment: @Werner is it possible to apply the same for [How to turn off an environment (e.g. tikzpicture) for faster draft compiling](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111566/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast: I'm sure it could. I'll add an answer there as well, for posterity. I don't consider the two questions duplicates though (definitely related)...

Comment: @Werner Your answer is very nice hence it's worth to see on other question also :). Thanks a lot.