# Is there an easy way of producing a pdf without pictures?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I want pdflatex to produce a PDF with the images shown as empty rectangles.

```
pdflatex thesis.tex
```

Will compile my thesis normally with pictures, but it takes about 5 min to compile

```
pdflatex -draftmode thesis.tex
```

Will compile my thesis, showing that pdflatex has interpreted all of my commands, but it won't show a PDF so that I can see that it has actually done what I want. It takes about 20 sec to run.

```
\includeonly{Chapter4}
```

Is faster, but gives a lot of errors making it harder to work out if my new bit of formatting code has done what I want. Also it isn't much faster.

I want something like

```
pdflatex -noimages thesis.tex
```

Which will create a PDF with empty rectangles where the images go, so that I can quickly check that the figures are in the right place, and any formatting, without having to wait 5 min between each attempt at formatting.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the figures included with `\includegraphcis`, if so the `draft` option will do the trick. How are you including the pictures?

Comment: This is peripheral to your question, but may be of interest: [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111595/21891)'s a way of removing all `tikzpicture`'s in your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer suggests

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

which is perfect for simple tex documents. However many of us use custom class files provided by universities or journals, and these files often contain

```
\usepackage[foo,bar,baz]{graphicx}
```

and we would rather not edit the provided class file.

There are two alternative solutions.

1) Call the custom class file with the draft class option

```
\documentclass[draft]{CustomClass}
```

This will send the draft option to every package declared in the file, causing many changes, but the graphics will be replaced by white boxes.

2) Send the draft option to the graphicx package. This must be done before the custom class is called.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass{CustomClass}
```

Thank you to Daniel.E.Shub, MMM and Heiko Oberdiek for saying this in the comments to the other question.

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

in your `.tex` file?

Comment: This is exactly what I want, and works perfectly. 

Thank you

Comment: There's also the `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` option, which will give you ugly black boxes instead. (Not sure what the advantage of that is, but it's there if you want it!)

Comment: The options `dvips` and `pdftex` should not be passed to `graphicx`; the package detects by itself what driver to use for output.

Comment: @JohnWickerson the draft and demo options are very different. The draft option requires the image to exist and gets the bounding box size correct. The demo option works without the file existing and just makes up a bounding box.

Comment: @egreg Corrected.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Ah, I see, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: You might also give the `draft` option as a class option instead (compared to the package option given in the answer). It might save some additional time depending on the other packages used. As the other packages then also use their draft mode (if they support one), this might change the document.

Comment: @MMM

What is a class option, and what is the code to add it?

Comment: @John1923 instead of doing `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` do `\documentclass[draft]{article}`, or whatever class you are using, this way all packages get the `draft` option.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Thanks, that is better than the original answer because I am using the `CUEDthesisPSnPDF` class which conforms to Cambridge university's thesis guidelines. The command `\usepackage{graphicx}` is buried in the class file, so I have to go into that each time I want to make it a draft. However the class itself is called at the top of my thesis.tex master document so I can just change `\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}` to `\documentclass[oneside,12pt,draft]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}`

Comment: @John1923 if you only want to pass the draft option to the `graphicx` package you can add `\RequirePackage[draft]{graphicx}` before the `\documentclass` line in you main file.

Comment: @egreg Some drivers are detectable (`pdftex`, `xetex`, `vtex`), others are not. Thus a package cannot detect `dvips`, for example. The user might run `dvipdfm` afterwards. IMHO it is perfectly ok, if someone specifies a DVI driver option that is not detectable.

Comment: Adding `\RequirePackage[draft]{graphicx}` before the `\documentclass{foo}` in my main `thesis.tex`causes an option clash when the class file defines graphicx with `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` Is there a command that will allow 'graphicx' to be fed options at multiple points in the code?

Comment: @John1923 @DanielEShub Options can be given to a package loaded by the document class by `\PassOptionsToPackage` before `\documentclass`. In this case `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}`. Package `graphicx` also provides an alternative, option `draft` can also be changed after package loading: `\setkeys{Gin}{draft}`.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek  `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}` Works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I mentioned `pdftex` and `dvips`; specifying `pdftex` would make it impossible to switch the document to use XeLaTeX without changing the option. Other drivers, as you say, are not automatically detected.