# h- and v- phantom a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to hide a tikzpicture :

Depending on a boolean, I want to see or not the tikzpicures of a document (show them on display, but hide them on paper) in order to students draw them.
The hidden tikzpicture as to leave its blank space.

`\vpanthom` or `\hphantom` don't work.

Comment: Could you check whether [How to turn off an environment (e.g. tikzpicture) for faster draft compiling](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111566/13304) is a duplicate?

Comment: I think it is not what I want, I want the tikzpicture to disappear but I want a white room instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine the `every picture` style and `execute at end picture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifhidepics
\hidepicsfalse
%\hidepicstrue % uncomment to hide tikzpicture

\ifhidepics
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={
execute at end picture={
\fill [white] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
}}}
\fi

\begin{document}
Something here.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {A};
\node at (2,5) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

More text.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {A};
\node at (2,2) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

Test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea how this may be used in Beamer so that one slide has a white room and the other has a TikZ drawing?

Comment: @OlivierMassicot Sounds like you want one of beamers overlay methods. Perhaps \uncover.