# Hidden environment doesn't compile if begins with "itemize"

Tags: errors, environments, comments

I'm writing a simple package to be used for homework exercises written by me and my colleagues. Depending on the package option, the document should compile with or without the answers. I do this by (re)defining an environment called `answer`. As the answer often contains listings, I use the comment feature of the package `verbatim` as was advised here in SE and as shown below. Everything works fine unless the answer begins with some other environment. I have found a simple workaround: the MWE can be compiled by placing an empty string `{}` in the beginning of the `answer` environment, but I do not understand, why the MWE cannot be compiled without this empty string? The error I've got is

```
 ! File ended while scanning use of \verbatim@.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{answer}[1]{\comment}{\endcomment}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{answer} %{}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item a 
    \end{itemize}
\end{answer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The two `\expandafter` tokens serve no purpose. You should consider the `comment` package, though.

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli, thank you very much, that solved the problem! Please convert your comment into an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you're right. I put them here following [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37925/how-to-make-latex-ignore-the-contents-of-an-environment/37945#37945). I remove them from my question as not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Converting my comment to an answer, and improving it a little:

Environments are defined, somewhat, like commands: they can take arguments or not.

```
\newenvironment{env-name}[<num of args>][<opt arg>]{<begin code>}{<end code>}
```

If the `[<num of args]` is set, the environment will expect an argument (or more). In your definition states the the environment should receive one mandatory argument (no optionals), therefore when you compile without the "empty string" `{}` an error rises, because the environment was expecting an argument and none was given.

Furthermore it's worth to note that the environments arguments are only valid on the `<begin code>` part, e.g.

```
\newenvironment{env-name}[1]{...}{something with #1}
```

won't work.