# Comment out input files through flags

Tags: input

Following up on a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79522/comment-out-lines-without-using-and-comment-enviroment) about universal processing of some hundreds of exercises to prepare for my students has arisen a new problem that I try to resolve ... however the fact is that I do not know if LaTeX can handle what I try to do nor know how to do it ...

Εach exercise is a separate small file, and refers to the entire spectrum of physics. I have input some **flags** within these separate files, such as energy, entropy,  solid body, etc. so that I can sort these.

**Well my question.**
Is there a way through these flags that can be used to printed only the input files that refer to a flag that I will choose in the main document without printing all other files? Νamely if I want only exercises containing **flag entropy** Is there a way to not print the `exercise.436` that does not contain **flag entropy** ... say something like `\chose{entropy}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% This piece of code its from previous question
%% And is due to @egreg

\newif\ifflags
\long\def\flags[#1]{%
  \ifflags
  \par
  \begingroup
  \let \\ \par
   \color{red}\small\\ \textbf{Flags: #1}%
  \par\medskip
  \endgroup
  \fi}

\flagstrue  % comment out for don't appears the flags
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\input{exercise.435.tex}
\input{exercise.436.tex}

\end{document
```

The files `exercise.435` at the beginning contains the following lines

```
\flags[energy, entropy, solid.boby]
here is the text of exercise.435.tex
```

The files `exercise.436` at the beginning contains the following lines

```
\flags[energy, solid.boby]
here is the text of exercise.436.tex
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way with LaTeX3 macros

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\enableflags}{ m }
 {
  \karathan_enable_flags:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\flags}{ O{} }
 {
  \karathan_flags:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq
\bool_new:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \karathan_enable_flags:n #1
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \karathan_flags:n #1
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_if_in:NnT \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq { ##1 } 
     { \clist_map_break:n { \bool_set_true:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool } }
   }
  \bool_if:NF \l_karathan_flag_found_bool { \endinput }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Enabled \texttt{energy}}

\enableflags{energy}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{entropy}}

\enableflags{entropy}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{solid.body}}

\enableflags{solid.body}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{energy}, \texttt{entropy}, \texttt{solid.body}}

\enableflags{energy, entropy, solid.body}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\end{document}
```

The `\enableflags` command receives as argument the list of flags you want to enable. Then `\flags` compares each item in its argument with this list. If no match is found, the file is closed and no more input from it is accepted (with `\endinput`).

[image]

---

If you want an *and* and not an *or* of the flags, here's how you can define the macro `\karathan_flags:n`:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \karathan_flags:n #1
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnF { #1 } { ##1 }
     { \seq_map_break:n { \bool_set_false:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool } }
   }
  \bool_if:NF \l_karathan_flag_found_bool { \endinput }
 }
```

If *all* set flags are in the argument of `\flags`, then the boolean remains true and `\endinput` is not executed.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,indentfirst}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\enableflags}{ m }
 {
  \karathan_enable_flags:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\resetflags}{ m }
 {
  \seq_gclear:N \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq
  \karathan_enable_flags:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\flags}{ O{} }
 {
  \karathan_flags:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq
\bool_new:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \karathan_enable_flags:n #1
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \karathan_flags:n #1
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_karathan_enabled_flags_seq
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnF { #1 } { ##1 }
     { \seq_map_break:n { \bool_set_false:N \l_karathan_flag_found_bool } }
   }
  \bool_if:NF \l_karathan_flag_found_bool
   %{  \texttt{(#1)}\par }
   { \endinput }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Enabled \texttt{energy}}

\enableflags{energy}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{entropy}}

\enableflags{entropy}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{energy}, \texttt{entropy}}

\enableflags{energy,entropy}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{solid.body}}

\enableflags{solid.body}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\section{Enabled \texttt{energy}, \texttt{entropy}, \texttt{solid.body}}

\enableflags{energy, entropy, solid.body}

\input{exercise.435.tex}

\input{exercise.436.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For not to violate the rules I will not say "thank you" but I will say that some of us owe so much to some of you who have real passion with TeX-LaTex etc :)

Comment: I asked exactly the same and @DavidCarlisle (copy-paste) :-)
Ηow I could change your code so that is "true" if simultaneously met two or more flags? as an example if I choose flags energy and entropy then file exercise.436 isn't displayed that having only flag energy ?

Comment: @karathan I added the change you requested

Comment: I have replaced the piece of macro, and while displaying the flags does not display the content of exercises, perhaps, something I do not understand correctly. I will testing again and will inform you of the result

Comment: @karathan These macros *don't* display the flags.

Comment: to me it only shows the flags, very strange!!

Comment: seems to ignore the command `\enableflags{...}` and prints the flags as text

Comment: @karathan Did you just replace the last definition? The rest should be exactly the same. (I've deleted some irrelevant comments, please do the same.)

Comment: I think there must be a problem with the I3packages because  I do not run properly neither the previous code now that I tried it again. I think the installation, of kile after installation of TexLive 2012 has some culpability. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Finally my fault...neither kile nor anything else. I wrote mistakenly in the files `exercise.435` and `exercise.436` ,this `\frags{...}` instead of `\flags[...]`. Everything finally works perfectly, sorry about yesterday's vigil... "mi permetta di dire grazie" :-)

Answer (score 6):

This version just use primitive TeX conditionals, you can specify any number of flags in separate `\chooseflag` commands, the file will be printed if it contains any chosen flag.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% This piece of code its from previous question
%% And is due to @egreg

\newif\ifflags
\long\def\flags[#1]{%
  {\xflags#1,xstopx,\endinput%
  \ifx\endinput\relax
  \ifflags
  \par
  \begingroup
  \let \\ \par
   \color{red}\small\\ \textbf{Flags: #1}%
  \par\medskip
  \endgroup
  \fi\fi}}

\def\xflags#1,#2{%
\csname xflags#1\endcsname
\xflags#2}

\def\xflagsxstopx#1{}

\def\chooseflag#1{\expandafter\def\csname xflags#1\endcsname{\let\endinput\relax}}

\chooseflag{entropy}

\flagstrue  % comment out for don't appears the flags
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\input{exercise.435.tex}
\input{exercise.436.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one flag in the code?

Comment: Sorry my english not help me ... you write it at the beginning :)

Comment: Ηow I could change your code so that is "true" if simultaneously met two or more flags?  as an example  if I choose flags `energy` and `entropy` then file `exercise.436`  isn't displayed that having only flag `energy`?

Comment: oh you want to _and_ the flags together not  _or_ ?? OK I misunderstood the requirement yes I'll update the code in a bit once I have a bit of time during day