# how to store page numbers in array and retrive them later?

Tags: page-numbering, arrays

I am working on one application where i need to store page numbers in an array and retrive them later to print index. I don't want to use the existing index function as i need to have control on it. How can i implement it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but  have a look here http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc and here to get an idea of what can be makes http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94766/the-numbering-of-exercises-automatically-on-table

Comment: you can directly use `\write` to work with external file of your own format, or define new commands that will use `\label` and `\pageref`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em very helpful to me your comment ... :) I was looking for something like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20957/how-to-use-a-write-command-inside-a-newenvironment I think it will be useful and to user15662

Comment: What's in the standard indexing facility that doesn't suit you?

Comment: Without a response to for example egreg's question, we can't really help so much here. Almost certainly the best approach will depend on your real requirements.