# List terms(/keywords) together with their definition and a glossary

Tags: indexing, glossaries

I want to be able to define terms/keywords and give definitions that might span multiple paragraphs. Given definitions of the following form:

```
\begin{definition}[Blue]
  Blue is one of ...
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Argument]
  An argument is ...
\end{definition}
```

I want to be able to refer to a definition with a command (e.g. `\usedef{blue}`) and I want to create two separate listings, both ordered lexicographically where the one is a normal glossary index (just the keyword and referenced pages) and the other is an overview of term and definition.

The `glossaries` package does something to this extent, however, it lacks support for my last requirement. Also I don't know how it handles multiple paragraphs of definition. There is an optional argument called `description` though.

What would be a good starting point to achieve my goal, or maybe there is a package that already provides this functionality?

It would look a bit like this. (Omitting the reference in a leading text) And don't mind the fonts please.
[image]

Comment: I can imagine a solution using LaTeX3 especially the modul l3prop.

Comment: Can you add a sketch of how you'd want the various pieces of information printed?

Comment: @egreg I've added an example picture with some annotation

Comment: What should the output of `\usedef{<id>}` be?

Comment: `\usedef{<id>}` should print the name and link it to the definition.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen so `\usedef{Blue}` would print `Blue` (as a link)? (A tip: if you precede a user name with `@` the user get's notified of your comment.)

Comment: @cgnieder Exactly.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen what about upper- and lowercase?

Comment: Maybe an option/different command for upper-/lowercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Combining `etoc` and `glossaries`

In my original answer (see below) I defined a custom environment for the definitions and used `etoc` to create a table of definitions (ToD) for them. However, since basically the task is to have the functionality of `glossaries` plus the ToD a better idea is to use `glossaries` for all its handy functionality and use `etoc` additionally for the ToD. The easiest way for this is to copy the `\listofdefinitions` from my original answer and define a custom glossary style that clones one of the predefined styles and adds the contents line for `etoc`. This way entries a sorted using `glossaries`' possibilities, i.e. either through `makeindex` or through `xindy`. Entries can be linked to through all the commands `glossaries` has to offer, e.g. the standard `\gls{<label>}`.

The code blow gives this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}

\usepackage[nopostdot,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
  \renewcommand\glossaryentryfield[5]{%
    % #1: label
    % #2: name
    % #3: description
    % #4: symbol
    % #5: page number(s)
    \etoctoccontentsline{definition}{\protect\numberline{##2}}%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3\glspostdescription\space##5
  }%
}

% this will display all definitions but nothing else as a toc:
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}%
  \etocsetlevel{definition}{1}% 'definition' entries will be included
  \etocsetlevel{section}{2}%  % sections are hidden
  \etocsettocstyle{\section{Foo}}{}%
  \etocsetstyle{definition}
    {}{}
    {\noindent\etocnumber\strut\leaders\etoctoclineleaders\hfill\etocpage\par}
    {\pagebreak[2]\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \tableofcontents
}

% use standard toc and hide definition entries
\etocsetlevel{definition}{6}

% dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

% define entries:
\newglossaryentry{foo}{
  name = Foo ,
  description = \lipsum*[1]
}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{
  name = Foo Bar ,
  description = \lipsum*[1-2]
}
\newglossaryentry{blue}{
  name = Blue ,
  description = \lipsum*[1]
}
\newglossaryentry{argument}{
  name = Argument ,
  description = \lipsum*[1]
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo Bar}
\subsection{Foo}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[2-4]

\gls{blue} and \gls{foo} and \gls{bar} and \gls{argument}

\appendix
\listofdefinitions

\renewcommand\glossaryname{Own name}
\glossarystyle{mylist}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

### Original answer

The picture reminds me somehow of [jfbu's answer to »The numbering of exercises automatically on table«](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95111/5049) and I thought this seems to be a similar task. So below you see the result of my first use of [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc)...

[image]

I define a simple `definition` environment:

```
\newcounter{definition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1]
  {%
    \refstepcounter{definition}%
    \etoctoccontentsline{definition}{\protect\numberline{#1}}%
    \par\noindent\textbf{#1}\quad
  }
  {\par\bigskip}
```

and a command `\listofdefinitions` that outputs the »definitions toc«:

```
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}%
  \etocsetlevel{definition}{1}% 'definition' entries will be included
  \etocsetlevel{section}{2}%  % sections are hidden
  \etocsettocstyle{\section{Foo}}{}%
  \etocsetstyle{definition}
    {}{}
    {\noindent\etocnumber\strut\leaders\etoctoclineleaders\hfill\etocpage\par}
    {\pagebreak[2]\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \tableofcontents
}
```

In order to demonstrate that the normal table of contents is not affected by this - at least not when `\etocsetlevel{definition}{6}` is called before - I added a dummy section and `\tableofcontents` to the document below.

The interesting part of the full code that produced the output shown above is this:

```
\appendix
\listofdefinitions

\section{Bar}
\begin{definition}{Blue}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Argument}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{definition}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}

% a simple `definition' environment:
\newcounter{definition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1]
  {%
    \refstepcounter{definition}%
    \etoctoccontentsline{definition}{\protect\numberline{#1}}%
    \par\noindent\textbf{#1}\quad
  }
  {\par\bigskip}

% this will display all definitions but nothing else as a toc:
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}%
  \etocsetlevel{definition}{1}% 'definition' entries will be included
  \etocsetlevel{section}{2}%  % sections are hidden
  \etocsettocstyle{\section{Foo}}{}%
  \etocsetstyle{definition}
    {}{}
    {\noindent\etocnumber\strut\leaders\etoctoclineleaders\hfill\etocpage\par}
    {\pagebreak[2]\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \tableofcontents
}

% use standard toc and hide definition entries
\etocsetlevel{definition}{6}

% dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo Bar}
\subsection{Foo}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Bar}
\lipsum[2-4]

\appendix
\listofdefinitions

\section{Bar}
\begin{definition}{Blue}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Argument}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Foo}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Bar}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Foo Bar}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just realized I forgot the `\usedef{}` requirement... I'll add something but this'll have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: When I use this code I get the following error `! Undefined control sequence.
\definition ...r {definition}\etoctoccontentsline 
                                                  {definition}`

Comment: Try updating your TeX distribution. `etoc` is rather new and has had a few updates already

Comment: Ah that did the trick. However, in my case this doesn't print the definitions in alphabetical order when showing the definitions, only in the index.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen Please see my edited answer

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but how did you obtain the pdf you show? I tried with running `pdflatex`, `makeindex` and again `pdflatex` on the file I stored your code in. `makeindex` tells me this: "Scanning input file definitions.tex...done (0 entries accepted, 65 rejected).
Nothing written in definitions.ind." The last text in the resulting PDF is the chapter header "A Foo".

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen You need to run `makeglossaries` instead of `makeindex`