# Enable and disable contents of \chapter command

Tags: conditionals, xkeyval

I have large set of contents for the user. For a different user I would like to show different contents. For this I would like to produce different output by showing and not showing some of the contents (say chapters sections subsection) of the document.

My Idea is: While writing chapter/section I declare it to enable showing to a specific user
by setting argument to true or false. For example,

> if (user1 == true) then  it should be there in `user1.pdf`

More specifically, something like:

Macro is:  `\chapter <chapterName1> [bool arg1][bool arg2][bool arg3]`

```
\chapter <chapterName1> [user1==true][user2==false][user3==false] 

\chapter <chapterName2> [user1==true][user2==true][user3==false]

\section <sectionName1> [user1==true][user2==true][user3==true]
```

If I pass `user1` and `user3` as 'True', then my output should contain

command (ex) : `\def\arg1=true, arg2=false, arg1=true \input{myfile}`

```
chapterName1

sectionName1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For a false condition, are you expecting the whole section to be deleted, or merely the invocation of a section header not to occur? Also, I'm not sure I understand the logic involved in your arguments. That is, what argi conditions define an overall true condition?

Comment: Hi, For the false condition "the whole section should not be shown"

Comment: I have edited my question. I guess it will be more clear. Thanks

Comment: @umaraman It reminds me of one of my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79522/comment-out-lines-without-using-and-comment-enviroment

Comment: Let's see if I understand correctly, the `[]` parameters following the chapter/section are the default allowabilities for that chap/sec.  At the beginning of the file, or on the command line, you would like to specify the target users for this particular build.  What I don't understand is, if user3 is true, he should not get chapterName1, and yet your example shows him getting it.  Are you proposing a means to override the defaults? [Also, do you have a typo by mentioning arg1 twice, and arg3 not at all in your "command ex" line?]

Comment: Hi Steven Thanks for you reply, Yes you got my idea of allow abilities.I gave two parameters user1 and user3, chapterName1 is allowable to user1 as well thats why output has chapterName1)

Answer (score 2):

You can start from here. The methods below feature the `environ` package to skip content, but you could also try to use the `comment` package for this purpose.

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\newcommand{\username}{user1}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{condchapter}[2][user]{
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{\username}=\z@
        \chapter{#2}
        \BODY
    \else
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{condchapter}[user1]{Title-1}

Some text.

\end{condchapter}

\begin{condchapter}[user2]{Title-2}

Some text.

\end{condchapter}

\renewcommand{\username}{user2}

\begin{condchapter}[user2]{Title-3}

Some text.

\end{condchapter}

\end{document}
```

Another possibility with the list of enabled users:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\username}{user1}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{condchapter}[2][user]{
    \IfSubStr{#1}{\username}{%
        \chapter{#2}
        \BODY
    }{}
    %\else
    %\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{condchapter}[user1]{Title-1}

Some text.

\end{condchapter}

\begin{condchapter}[user2]{Title-2}

Some text.

\end{condchapter}

\renewcommand{\username}{user2}

\begin{condchapter}[user2, user3]{Title-3}

Some text.

\end{condchapter}

\end{document}
```

PS: to create all files at once you can start from the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the)

---

Another possibility is to use only the [`comment` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) for this purpose without the modifications to the `chapter` command.