# Verbatim Text Inside Environment which is inside a Boolean Condition

Tags: environments, conditionals, verbatim, code

My code looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\showsolution}{1}
\NewEnviron{mysolution}{
\if\showsolution1
    \fbox{\BODY}
\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{mysolution}
    \begin{verbatim}
       code code code
    \end{verbatim}
 \end{mysolution}

 \end{document}
```

where the `solution` environment is created with the `NewEnviron` package as I want to display the solution depending on an if statement. However, if I now want to put code inside my solution by using verbatim I get the runaway argument /  Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
Edit: with the MWE above the error changes to missing \item. However, commenting out the verbatim inside the error disappears so it is still the same issue eventhough the error changed.

I guess the solution is something similar to the fragile option in `beamer`'s frame environment but I dont know wether there are similar options for the `environ` package. So how can I place verbatim text (or at least code) inside an if statement?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post such fragments only. Post a complete document; as it stands there is no `\if` statement yet. And you environment ends with `solution`, not with `mysolution` ;-)

Comment: sorry, i edited it.

Comment: You can't press verbatim content into a macro, i.e. `\fbox{\BODY}` won't work here

Comment: But the error still appears even after removing the `\fbox` command. I.e. it is not possible to display code depending on an if-statement?

Comment: It should not even work without the `\if` statement, since `\BODY` is a macro too!

Comment: I see the problem. But what could be a solution? I can't believe that it is not possible at all to show code depending on an if statement

Comment: It's possible, but I have no idea for `\BODY`.

Comment: you can not use verbatim in such an environment, look at fancyvrb and similar packages that allow you to define specific verbatim enviornments

Comment: Untested thought. Use the `comment` package and  toggle whether the `mysolution` environment is commented out.

Comment: Related: [How to put `\verb` command inside of `\textbf{}` block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/5764)

Comment: See also: [framed - How to frame any environment like minipage and others? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433450/how-to-frame-any-environment-like-minipage-and-others) & [conditionals - Hide custom environment content based on boolean - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/hide-custom-environment-content-based-on-boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies. The suggestion by Steven was very nice however had the disadvantage that one would need multiple boxes (which have to be defined outside the actual solution environment) if one wished to write text between code snippets.

Another way is the `lstinline` command from the `listings` package. It works inside the solution environment and one can at least write inline code. But this packages offers another command, `lstinputlisting` which allows to display code from an external file. One can then specify with the options `firstline` and `lastline` which sections of the code one wants to display. Disadvantage of that approach is of course 1) one needs an additional file and 2) adding or deleting code requires to adjust the first/lastline options

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ThisMWEasFile}
 1 blah &$ blah !
 2 Blah!@
 3 blah &$ blah @
 4 Blah!@
 5 blah &$ blah #
 6 Blah!@
 7 blah &$ blah $
 8 Blah!@
 9 blah &$ blah %
10 Blah!@
11 blah &$ blah ^
12 Blah!@
13 blah &$ blah &
14 Blah!@
15 blah &$ blah *
16 Blah!@
\end{filecontents*}

\newif\ifshowsolution
\showsolutiontrue

\NewEnviron{mysolution}{
\ifshowsolution
    \BODY
\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

    \item[Question 1:] Question with solution.\\
        \begin{mysolution}
            \lstinputlisting[firstline=1, lastline=5]{ThisMWEasFile.tex}
        \end{mysolution}
    \item[Question 2:] Question with solution.\\
        \begin{mysolution}
            \lstinputlisting[firstline=6, lastline=10]{ThisMWEasFile.tex}
            \textbf{text text text}
            \lstinputlisting[firstline=11, lastline=15]{ThisMWEasFile.tex}
        \end{mysolution}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of making your MWE self-contained.  I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

With the `scontents` package it is very easy to achieve what you are looking for.  Everything stored in memory including the content `verbatim`. If you want you can also save the content to external files using the key `write-env=file.tex`. I modified your example file a bit, the output is the same :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[store-env=solutions]{scontents}
%\newif\ifshowsolution
%\showsolutiontrue
%\ifshowsolution
\setupsc{print-env=true}
%\fi
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\item[Question 1:] Question with solution.\\
\begin{scontents}
\begin{verbatim}
 1 blah &$ blah !
 2 Blah!@
 3 blah &$ blah @
 4 Blah!@
 5 blah &$ blah #
\end{verbatim}
\end{scontents}
\item[Question 2:] Question with solution.\\
\begin{scontents}
\begin{verbatim}
6 Blah!@
7 blah &$ blah $
8 Blah!@
9 blah &$ blah %
10 Blah!@
\end{verbatim}
\textbf{text text text}
\begin{verbatim}
11 blah &$ blah ^
12 Blah!@
13 blah &$ blah &
14 Blah!@
15 blah &$ blah *
16 Blah!@
\end{verbatim}
\end{scontents}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, `verbatim` content cannot be processed as the argument to a macro.  Here, however, the `verbatimbox` package allows verbatim content to be placed (unprinted) into a LaTeX box that can be later recalled by way of macro.  Then, you can use the if condition to determine whether or not to execute the macro containing the verbatim content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newif\ifsoln
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\solutionA}
\code #$code code
\end{myverbbox}
Here, 
\solntrue
\ifsoln
\fbox{\solutionA}
\fi
is printed, whereas here,
\solnfalse
\ifsoln
\fbox{\solutionA}
\fi
it is not printed, based on an if condition.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Trying to employ the form of the OP's question, this might be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,verbatimbox}

\newif\ifshowsolution
\NewEnviron{mysolution}{
\ifshowsolution
    \fbox{\BODY}
\fi}

\begin{document}
\showsolutiontrue
\begin{verbbox}
code code code
\end{verbbox}

Here it shows:
\begin{mysolution}
    \theverbbox
\end{mysolution}

\showsolutionfalse
Here it does not:
\begin{mysolution}
    \theverbbox
\end{mysolution}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this solution. However, what I don't like here is that the code block is defined outside the solution environment (I know and as stated above, this seems to be necessary by the construction of verbatim), but this is then very confusing. Consider a situation like this:

code
text
code
text
code

this would require me to define 3 verbatim boxes...

Comment: @SydAmerikaner What you say is correct, and I understand why you consider such an approach non-desirable.  However, I will let the code stand until/unless a better answer is posted.

Comment: Sure! This is still a good work around and applicable if the solution for instance was code only or one was fine with writing text as comments inside the code (i.e. the verbatimbox).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `exam` document class. With the `solution` environment you write your solutions and with the `answers` option you determine that you want your solutions to be printed out.

Comment: have you tested this? because I guess that the exam class uses a similar construction method as I do for the solution environment

Comment: Yes, I have. It is efficient and flexible. The exam class also has the boolean variable `\ifprintanswers`. You can use this variable to add further changes to the document beyond printing the answers with the `answers` option.

Comment: You can't use verbatim in the `exam` document class... it's indeed, the same problem.

Comment: @tchevrier I have just tested it. Using `\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}`. I have tested `\verb|...|` and `\begin{verbatim} content... \end{verbatim}` inside and outside the solution environment. All work fine.