# How to frame any environment like minipage and others?

Tags: minipage, framed, fbox

How to frame an environment like `\minipage` and others in a frame box.

> Note: I tried `\fbox` and never worked, I always get errors
>   This is my code

```
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\small
\begin{verbatim}

[2018-05-25 19:21:48 EDT] iverilog '-Wall' design.sv testbench.sv  && unbuffer vvp a.out  
a=  2, b=  5, outsum=  7, true_sum=  7, cout=0
a=  2, b= 34, outsum= 36, true_sum= 36, cout=0
a=  2, b= 63, outsum= 65, true_sum= 65, cout=0
a=  2, b= 92, outsum= 94, true_sum= 94, cout=0
a=  2, b=121, outsum=123, true_sum=123, cout=0
a=  2, b=150, outsum=152, true_sum=152, cout=0
a=  9, b=  5, outsum= 14, true_sum= 14, cout=0
a=  9, b= 34, outsum= 43, true_sum= 43, cout=0
a=  9, b= 63, outsum= 72, true_sum= 72, cout=0
a=  9, b= 92, outsum=101, true_sum=101, cout=0    
a=  9, b=121, outsum=130, true_sum=130, cout=0
a=  9, b=150, outsum=159, true_sum=159, cout=0
a= 16, b=  5, outsum= 21, true_sum= 21, cout=0
a= 16, b= 34, outsum= 50, true_sum= 50, cout=0
a= 16, b= 63, outsum= 79, true_sum= 79, cout=0
a= 16, b= 92, outsum=108, true_sum=108, cout=0
a= 16, b=121, outsum=137, true_sum=137, cout=0
a= 16, b=150, outsum=166, true_sum=166, cout=0
Done
\end{verbatim}

\end{minipage}}
```

and this the errors I got

> Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete. \end{minipage}}
>
> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{minipage}}
>
> Improper \prevdepth. \chapter
>
> Missing \endgroup inserted. \chapter
>
> Missing } inserted. \chapter

Comment: you don't say how you used `\fbox` but `\fbox{\begin{minipage}{2cm}zzzz\end{minipage}}` frames a minipage. So it is not clear what problem your question is asking about.

Comment: I tried `\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{verbatim} couple lines of text \end{verbatim}\end{minipage}}` and I got errors and never works, I searched a lot till I found `framed` package, and that solved my problem

Comment: A statement such as "I got errors" is not very descriptive. *Which errors* did you get? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: \fbox is wider than what it contains (by 2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule), so if the contents are already \linewidth, then it is too wide for the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a package [framed](https://ctan.org/pkg/framed?lang=en) you can easily use to frame any environment

```
\usepackage{framed}
.
.
.
\begin{framed}
any thing to be framed
\end{framed}
```

Comment: Yes, and furthermore it can break across pages, which minipage cannot do.

Comment: You may want to instead look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: If you put minipages next to one another in `framed`, the first one can change size and displace the second one.