# How to switch easily between including solutions and not including solutions in an exam pdf

Tags: pdftex

I'm writing an exam for a class, and I'd like to write the solutions as I write the exam. However, I'd like to be able to go back and from between generating pdfs with solutions included and without them. Ideally, the solutions could be included in some custom environment, which can be "turned off/on" by modifying a small piece of code in the preamble. I.e., when turned off, they should effectively be commented out.

The brute force solution would be to manually comment out every solution when generating the exam without solutions, but it would be nice if there were a cleaner way.

How can I most easily do this?

Comment: There are packages designed for this like [xsim](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim), and the [exam](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) document class, etc, which have a lot of features. Too many probably, but they definitely do what you ask.

Comment: Probably wanting something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15510/1750 and then put your solutions in `\begin{solution}` ... `\end{solution}`

Comment: in fact as you already said you are willing to use a custom environment, this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I added an answer to the duplicate focusing a bit more on the exercise/solution part. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660831/38080)

Answer (score 0):

What about `ifdefined`?

```
\documentclass{article}   
\newcommand*{\SHOWSOLUTION}{}  % comment out to hide solution

\begin{document}
Problem
\ifdefined\SHOWSOLUTION
    Solution
\else
    Think yourself.
\fi
\end{document}
```

As already mentioned by others, the document class [exam](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf) offers many features in this regard.

Further alternatives you find at a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build).