# What is wrong with the following environment definition?

Tags: environments, environment-variables, technical-environment

I want to define an environment to hide text, with warning about it before and after in the pdf-output. What is wrong with the following definition?

```
\newenvironment{foldit}
{NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW\\ NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW\\ \iffalse}
{\fi ~~\\ NB! NB! FOLDEDTEXTABOVE \\ NB! NB! FOLDEDTEXTABOVE}
```

When I try to enclose some texts with `\begin{foldit} .... \end{foldit}`, I get the error message: Incomplete `\iffalse; all text was ignored after line 105.`

Comment: As for the explanation *why* this does not work see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14616/82917.

Comment: Actually special case of [conditionals - Hide custom environment content based on boolean - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/hide-custom-environment-content-based-on-boolean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) to define `foldit`. It handles the environment definition in a similar way you'd expect from `\newcommand`, with the argument being `\BODY` - the body of the environment (between `\begin{<env>}`...`\end{<env>}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,lipsum}

\NewEnviron{foldit}{%
  \par\noindent NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW
  \par\noindent NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW
  %\BODY
  \par\noindent NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT ABOVE
  \par\noindent NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT ABOVE
}
\begin{document}

1: \lipsum[1]

\begin{foldit}
2: \lipsum[1]
\end{foldit}

3: \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug: If I try this over several sections, it crashes.

Comment: @Sapiens: Are you nesting them? Ps. I should have used `\BODY`, not `\Body`.

Comment: I solved the problem now.

Comment: I added colors for the messages to stand out.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try package `environ` or `comment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{foldit}{%
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW\\
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW\\
%\BODY
NB! NB! FOLDEDTEXTABOVE\\
NB! NB! FOLDEDTEXTABOVE\\
}

\NewEnviron{unfoldit}{%
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW\\
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW\\
\BODY\\
NB! NB! FOLDEDTEXTABOVE\\
NB! NB! FOLDEDTEXTABOVE\\
}

\begin{document}
Line~1.

\begin{comment}
Line~2.
\end{comment}

Line~3.

\begin{foldit}
Line~4.
\end{foldit}

\begin{unfoldit}
Line~5.
\end{unfoldit}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I want the output:

Line 1.
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT ABOVE
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT ABOVE
Line 3.
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT BELOW
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT ABOVE
NB! NB! FOLDED TEXT ABOVE
Line 4.

Comment: I tried using \begin{comment} and \end{comment} instead of \iffalse and \fi in the definition of the new environment. The definition was accepted, but the text was not commented out.

Comment: @Sapiens, just updated my answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. This time Werner beat you to it with a minute! :)

Comment: @Sapiens, cool!!